# Using namedtuple._replace with a variable as a fieldname

Tags: python, namedtuple

Can I reference a namedtuple fieldame using a variable?

```
from collections import namedtuple
import random 

Prize = namedtuple("Prize", ["left", "right"]) 

this_prize = Prize("FirstPrize", "SecondPrize")

if random.random() > .5:
    choice = "left"
else:
    choice = "right"
    
#retrieve the value of "left" or "right" depending on the choice
print "You won", getattr(this_prize,choice)
 
#replace the value of "left" or "right" depending on the choice
this_prize._replace(choice  = "Yay") #this doesn't work

print this_prize
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Tuples are immutable, and so are NamedTuples. They are not supposed to be changed!

`this_prize._replace(choice  = "Yay")` calls `_replace` with the keyword argument `"choice"`. It doesn't use `choice` as a variable and tries to replace a field by the name of `choice`.

`this_prize._replace(**{choice  : "Yay"} )` would use whatever `choice` is as the fieldname

`_replace` returns a new NamedTuple. You need to reasign it: `this_prize = this_prize._replace(**{choice  : "Yay"} )`

Simply use a dict or write a normal class instead!

Comment: I'm trying to optimize a data structure for speed. 
I was hoping I could use namedtuples, but I would have to change them in place. Perhaps I'll have to  use something else. See:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2127680/python-optimizing-or-at-least-getting-fresh-ideas-for-a-tree-generator

Comment: I had a case where I wouldn't alter most of the tuples, but only a few of them, so `_replace` is the way to go. This answer helped me a lot (more than the official doc).

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> choice = 'left'
>>> this_prize._replace(**{choice: 'Yay'})         # you need to assign this to this_prize if you want
Prize(left='Yay', right='SecondPrize')
>>> this_prize
Prize(left='FirstPrize', right='SecondPrize')         # doesn't modify this_prize in place
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I see what you mean.

Comment: But really, why are you using a named tuple for this?  It sounds like you want a dict.