# Why does Python not support record type? (i.e. mutable namedtuple)

Tags: python, collections, namedtuple

Why does Python not support a record type natively? It's a matter of having a mutable version of namedtuple.

I could use `namedtuple._replace`. But I need to have these records in a collection and since `namedtuple._replace` creates another instance, I also need to modify the collection which becomes messy quickly.

Background:
I have a device whose attributes I need to get by polling it over TCP/IP. i.e. its representation is a mutable object.

Edit:
I have a set of devices for whom I need to poll.

Edit:
I need to iterate through the object displaying its attributes using PyQt. I know I can add special methods like `__getitem__` and `__iter__`, but I want to know if there is an easier way.

Edit:
I would prefer a type whose attribute are fixed (just like they are in my device), but are mutable.

Comment: Create a class, or use a dict.  Both are mutable, both allow you to access the values within them by name.

Comment: @dappawit, that is correct. But with dict, I will not have the convenience of having attributes as fields. I was avoiding class, because I need to iterate through the object treating it as a collection of attributes. I will edit my post to specify this requirement. I know I could always add special methods to treat it like a collection. But I am wondering whether there is any easier way.

Comment: A class instance has a `__dict__` attribute which is a dictionary.  You can iterate through that.  Look at the answer from Cameron and comment by Chris Lutz.

Comment: Thanks dappawit. I wanted to use an existing type without simulating a collection type using special methods. But yes, I will have to do that.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

### Python <3.3

You mean something like this?

```
class Record(object):
    __slots__= "attribute1", "attribute2", "attribute3",

    def items(self):
        "dict style items"
        return [
            (field_name, getattr(self, field_name))
            for field_name in self.__slots__]

    def __iter__(self):
        "iterate over fields tuple/list style"
        for field_name in self.__slots__:
            yield getattr(self, field_name)

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        "tuple/list style getitem"
        return getattr(self, self.__slots__[index])

>>> r= Record()
>>> r.attribute1= "hello"
>>> r.attribute2= "there"
>>> r.attribute3= 3.14

>>> print r.items()
[('attribute1', 'hello'), ('attribute2', 'there'), ('attribute3', 3.1400000000000001)]
>>> print tuple(r)
('hello', 'there', 3.1400000000000001)
```

Note that the methods provided are just a sample of possible methods.

### Python ≥3.3 update

You can use [`types.SimpleNamespace`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/types.html#types.SimpleNamespace):

```
>>> import types
>>> r= types.SimpleNamespace()
>>> r.attribute1= "hello"
>>> r.attribute2= "there"
>>> r.attribute3= 3.14
```

`dir(r)` would provide you with the attribute names (filtering out all `.startswith("__")`, of course).

Comment: That is great. Appreciate your answer. Just that I was hoping for a built-in/standard library data structure.

Comment: SimpleNamespace meets the need. Thanks.

Comment: wtf! Python continues to mess up their module logic.. why is this not in collections?

Comment: @u0b34a0f6ae Looking at the way that SimpleNamespace is implemented, it kind of makes sense to put it in `types`. If you look at lots of the "classes" in the `types` module, you'll notice that they are all obtained by using the `type` function to extract the type backing a particular value (e.g. `LambdaType = type(lambda: None)`). Guess how SimpleNamespace is implemented? `SimpleNamespace = type(sys.implementation)`.

Comment: @u0b34a0f6ae Because it is not a collection, in the same way an empty class like `class X(): pass` is not a collection. Most importantly, it has no notion of iteration or size. Why do you think it should be in `collections`?

Comment: Note that ``list(r.__dict__)`` will return user defined attribute names, without need for "__" filtering.

Answer (score 18):

Is there any reason you can't use a regular dictionary? It seems like the attributes don't have a specific ordering in your particular situation.

Alternatively, you could also use a class instance (which has nice attribute access syntax). You could use `__slots__` if you wish to avoid having a `__dict__` created for each instance.

I've also just found a [recipe for "records"](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576555/), which are described as mutable named-tuples. They are implemented using classes.

Update:

Since you say order is important for your scenario (and you want to iterate through all the attributes) an `OrderedDict` seems to be the way to go. This is part of the standard `collections` module as of Python 2.7; there are other [implementations](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576693/) floating around the internet for Python < 2.7.

To add attribute-style access, you can subclass it like so:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

class MutableNamedTuple(OrderedDict):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MutableNamedTuple, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._initialized = True

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        try:
            return self[name]
        except KeyError:
            raise AttributeError(name)

    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        if hasattr(self, '_initialized'):
            super(MutableNamedTuple, self).__setitem__(name, value)
        else:
            super(MutableNamedTuple, self).__setattr__(name, value)
```

Then you can do:

```
>>> t = MutableNamedTuple()
>>> t.foo = u'Crazy camels!'
>>> t.bar = u'Yay, attribute access'
>>> t.foo
u'Crazy camels!'
>>> t.values()
[u'Crazy camels!', u'Yay, attribute access']
```

Comment: You could even subclass the `dict` class and make (IIRC) `__getattr__` and `__setattr__` synonymous with `__getitem__` and `__setitem__` respectively.

Comment: @Chris: I like that method best, I think (and your memory's correct, those are the right methods)

Comment: +1 for specifying that __slots__ is created once for each class while __dict__ is created for each instance. I have edited my question to include need for an ordering. Also, I am aware of this record recipe; however I am wondering why Python community thought there is no need for a standard record type.

Comment: If you need ordering, try OrderedDict. I believe it is also in the collections module.

Comment: Thanks dappawit. I would prefer a type whose attribute are fixed (just like they are in my device), but are mutable. I think I may have to go for the record type as specified by Cameron.

Comment: I'd suggest it's a bad idea to put Tuple in the name of the example here when it doesn't act like a tuple. Better to call it a record or something else.

Comment: I've been playing with the recordtype recipe you link to from George Sakkis and it seems to work quite well for me, though at a small performance price to specifying the entire class by hand.

Comment: @ChrisLutz @Cameron Using `getattr` sounds interesting but I recommends against that since the field names would collide with the dict's public methods like `get` or `items`. That could make funny bugs.

Answer (score 11):

This can be done using an empty class and instances of it, like this:

```
>>> class a(): pass
... 
>>> ainstance = a()
>>> ainstance.b = 'We want Moshiach Now'
>>> ainstance.b
'We want Moshiach Now'
>>>
```

Comment: Also, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2157561/python-using-namedtuple-replace-with-a-variable-as-a-fieldname/2157742#2157742) to [this stackoverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2157561/541412) for more information.

Comment: Thanks Abafei.  I would prefer a type whose attribute are fixed (just like they are in my device), but are mutable. I have updated the question accordingly.

Answer (score 10):

There's a library similar to namedtuple, but mutable, called recordtype.

Package home: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/recordtype

Simple example:

```
from recordtype import recordtype

Person = recordtype('Person', 'first_name last_name phone_number')
person1 = Person('Trent', 'Steele', '637-3049')
person1.last_name = 'Terrence';

print person1
# Person(first_name=Trent, last_name=Terrence, phone_number=637-3049)
```

Simple default value example:

```
Basis = recordtype('Basis', [('x', 1), ('y', 0)])
```

Iterate through the fields of `person1` in order:

```
map(person1.__getattribute__, Person._fields)
```

Comment: [namedlist](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/namedlist/1.4) is an updated package by the same author which supports python 3 and is actively developed as of 2014.

Answer (score 9):

This question is old, but just for the sake of completeness, Python 3.7 has [dataclasses](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html) which are pretty much records.

```
>>> from dataclasses import dataclass
>>>
>>> @dataclass
... class MyRecord:
...     name: str
...     age: int = -1
...
>>> rec = MyRecord('me')
>>> rec.age = 127
>>> print(rec)
MyRecord(name='me', age=127)
```

The attrs third party library provides more functionality for both Python 2 and Python 3. Nothing wrong with vendoring dependencies either if the requirement is more around things you can't keep locally rather than specifically only using the stdlib. dephell has a nice helper for doing that.

Answer (score 4):

This answer duplicates [another one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29290359/existence-of-mutable-named-tuple-in-python/29419745#29419745).
There is a mutable alternative to `collections.namedtuple` - [recordclass](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/recordclass).

It has same API and minimal memory footprint (actually it also faster). It support assignments. For example:

```
from recordclass import recordclass

Point = recordclass('Point', 'x y')

>>> p = Point(1, 2)
>>> p
Point(x=1, y=2)
>>> print(p.x, p.y)
1 2
>>> p.x += 2; p.y += 3; print(p)
Point(x=3, y=5)
```

There is more complete [example](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/urls/bitbucket.org/intellimath/recordclass/raw/default/examples/what_is_recordclass.ipynb) (it also include performance comparisons).

Answer (score 2):

In the closely related [Existence of mutable named tuple in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29290359/341970) question 13 tests are used for comparing 6 mutable alternatives to `namedtuple`.

**The latest [namedlist](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/namedlist/) 1.7 [passes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34723835/341970) all of these tests with both Python 2.7 and Python 3.5** as of Jan 11, 2016. **It is a pure python implementation.**

The second best candidate according to these tests is the [`recordclass`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/recordclass) which is a C extension. Of course, it depends on your requirements whether a C extension is preferred or not.

For further details, especially for the tests, see [Existence of mutable named tuple in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29290359/341970)

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this`dict`subclass which is its own `__dict__`. The basic concept is the same as that of the ActiveState [AttrDict](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576972-attrdict/) recipe, but the implementation is simpler. The result is something more mutable than you need since both an instance's attributes and their values are changeable. Although the attributes aren't ordered, you can iterate through the current ones and/or their values.

```
class Record(dict):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Record, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.__dict__ = self
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on several useful tricks gathered over time, this "frozenclass" decorator does pretty much everything needed: http://pastebin.com/fsuVyM45

Since that code is over 70% documentation and tests, I won't say more here.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complete mutable namedtuple I made, which behaves like a list and is totally compatible with it.

```
class AbstractNamedArray():
    """a mutable collections.namedtuple"""
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        inst = object.__new__(cls)  # to rename the class
        inst._list = len(cls._fields)*[None]
        inst._mapping = {}
        for i, field in enumerate(cls._fields):
            inst._mapping[field] = i
        return inst

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if len(kwargs) == 0 and len(args) != 0:
            assert len(args) == len(self._fields), 'bad number of arguments'
            self._list = list(args)
        elif len(args) == 0 and len(kwargs) != 0:
            for field, value in kwargs.items():
                assert field in self._fields, 'field {} doesn\'t exist'
                self._list[self._mapping[field]] = value
        else:
            raise ValueError("you can't mix args and kwargs")

    def __getattr__(self, x):
        return object.__getattribute__(self, '_list')[object.__getattribute__(self, '_mapping')[x]]

    def __setattr__(self, x, y):
        if x in self._fields:
            self._list[self._mapping[x]] = y
        else:
            object.__setattr__(self, x, y)

    def __repr__(self):
        fields = []
        for field, value in zip(self._fields, map(self.__getattr__, self._fields)):
            fields.append('{}={}'.format(field, repr(value)))
        return '{}({})'.format(self._name, ', '.join(fields))

    def __iter__(self):
        yield from self._list

    def __list__(self):
        return self._list[:]

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self._fields)

    def __getitem__(self, x):
        return self._list[x]

    def __setitem__(self, x, y):
        self._list[x] = y

    def __contains__(self, x):
        return x in self._list

    def reverse(self):
        self._list.reverse()

    def copy(self):
        return self._list.copy()


def namedarray(name, fields):
    """used to construct a named array (fixed-length list with named fields)"""
    return type(name, (AbstractNamedarray,), {'_name': name, '_fields': fields})
```

Answer (score 0):

As [tzot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6899/tzot) [stated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5491708/1171227), since Python ≥3.3, Python *does* have a mutable version of namedtuple: [`types.SimpleNamespace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html#types.SimpleNamespace).

These things are very similar to the new [C# 9 Records](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-9#record-types).

Here are some usage examples:

#### Positional constructor arguments

```py
>>> import types
>>>
>>> class Location(types.SimpleNamespace):
...   def __init__(self, lat=0, long=0):
...     super().__init__(lat=lat, long=long)
...
>>> loc_1 = Location(49.4, 8.7)
```

#### Pretty repr

```
>>> loc_1
Location(lat=49.4, long=8.7)
```

#### Mutable

```
>>> loc_2 = Location()
>>> loc_2
Location(lat=0, long=0)
>>> loc_2.lat = 49.4
>>> loc_2
Location(lat=49.4, long=0)
```

#### Value semantics for equality

```
>>> loc_2 == loc_1
False
>>> loc_2.long = 8.7
>>> loc_2 == loc_1
True
```

#### Can add attributes at runtime

```
>>> loc_2.city = 'Heidelberg'
>>> loc_2
```