# Set an optional variable in named tuple

Tags: python

```
from collections import namedtuple

FooT = namedtuple('Foo', 'foo bar')
def Foo(foo=None, bar=None):
  return FooT(foo,bar)

foo = Foo()
foo.foo = 29
throws attribute error
```

So, my use case is a datastructure which have optional fields.. but should be able to modify it if desired..

Comment: It's because tuples are immutable, you can't modify them once you created them.

Comment: As enrico pointed out below, immutable does not mean you never need to change data: `_replace()` can be used to update values and return a new immutable structure.  Check out [`typing.NamedTuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.NamedTuple) as of 3.6.1 it supports default values.

Answer (score 5):

A [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) should be appropriate for what you want.  It works by providing it a function on construction which it calls every time an unset element is accessed.  Here's a demo:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> d = defaultdict(lambda:None)
>>> d['foo'] = 10
>>> d['bar'] = 5
>>> print d['baz']
None
>>> d['baz'] = 15
>>> print d['baz']
15
```

Answer (score 5):

Tuples are, by definition, immutable. Namedtuples follow this pattern as well.

In python3 it appears there is a SimpleNamespace [1] that you can use. If you want to simply use a read/write datastructure though you could create a class and put constraints on its members.

[1] - [Why Python does not support record type i.e. mutable namedtuple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5227839/why-python-does-not-support-record-type-i-e-mutable-namedtuple)

Answer (score 2):

A namedtuple, like a tuple is not modifiable. Since the question is about namedtuple, in some case you may find ok (or sometimes even preferable) to create a new object with the [`_replace`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.somenamedtuple._replace) method. Of course the other references to the same object will be unchanged.

```
from collections import namedtuple

FooT = namedtuple('Foo', 'foo bar')
def Foo(foo=None, bar=None):
  return FooT(foo,bar)

foo = Foo()
foo = foo._replace(foo=29)
```

Answer (score 2):

For a slight variation on the above answers, why not extend the advice in the [tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/classes.html#odds-and-ends) and have a class that returns None for any undefined attribute?  For example:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return None
```

This is much the same as a defaultdict, but accessible via direct attributes much like a named tuple.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use a class?

```
class Foo(object):

   def __init__(foo=None, bar=None):
     self.foo = foo
     self.bar = bar

foo = Foo()
foo.foo = 29
```