# Python: derived classes access dictionary of base class in the same memory location

Tags: python, inheritance, dictionary

I'm wondering why a dictionary, that is defined in a base class and is accessed from derived classes, is obviously present only in one memory location. 
A short example:

```
class BaseClass:
    _testdict = dict()
    _testint = 0

    def add_dict_entry(self):
        self._testdict["first"] = 1

    def increment(self):
        self._testint += 1

class Class1(BaseClass):
    pass

class Class2(BaseClass):
    pass

object1 = Class1()
object2 = Class2()

object1.add_dict_entry()
object1.increment()
print(object2._testdict)
print(object2._testint)
```

and the output is:

```
{'first': 1}
0
```

Why does a call to the "add_dict_entry" of object1 affect the dictionary of object2? Using integers ("increment") the base class variable is not affected.

Thanks a lot.

Lorenz

Comment: Related: ["Least Astonishment" in Python: The Mutable Default Argument](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1132941)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dictionary and array as class vs. instance variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7277094/dictionary-and-array-as-class-vs-instance-variables)

Answer (score 9):

It's because `_testdict` is a class variable: it's defined only once, when the class is initially constructed. If you want it to be separate for each instance, make it an instance variable:

```
class BaseClass:
    _testint = 0

    def __init__(self):
        self._testdict = dict()

    def add_dict_entry(self):
        self._testdict["first"] = 1
```

(Note that you'd need to create `__init__` methods for `Class1` and `Class2` as well, both of which would have to call `BaseClass.__init__(self)`).

`_testint` behaves differently because you're performing a rebinding operation on it rather than a mutating operation. ints are immutable, so you can't "change" one- `self._testint += 1` is just syntactic sugar for `self._testint = self._testint + 1`. Similarly, you can perform a rebinding operation on `self._testdict` that won't be shared between instances- for example, `self._testdict = {}` will reset *only* that instance's `_testdict`.

Comment: +1; the only thing left to explain to the OP is why `_testint` and `_testdict` behave differently.

Comment: @DSM: Also just found a possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7277094/dictionary-and-array-as-class-vs-instance-variables) whose answer explains it pretty thoroughly.

Answer (score 2):

In python, int is immutable, therefore the += operation will rebound the class variable into an instance variables. On the other hand, a dictionary indexing mutates the dictionary in place. A more comparable example would be

```
def add_dict_entry(self):
    # create a new dict
    tmp = dict(self._testdict)
    tmp["first"] = 1

    # shadow the class variable with an instance variables
    self._testdict = tmp
```