# Class and instance attributes

Tags: python

I learned that Python class attributes are like static data members in C++. However, I got confused after trying the following code:

```
>>> class Foo:
...     a=1
... 
>>> f1=Foo();
>>> f2=Foo()
>>> f1.a
1
>>> f1.a=5
>>> f1.a
5
>>> f2.a
1
```

Shouldn't f2.a also equal 5?

If a is defined as a list instead of an integer, the behavior is expected:

```
>>> class Foo:
...     a=[]
... 
>>> f1=Foo();
>>> f2=Foo()
>>> f1.a
[]
>>> f1.a.append(5)
>>> f1.a
[5]
>>> f2.a
[5]
```

I looked at
[What is the difference between class and instance attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/207000/python-difference-between-class-and-instance-attributes), but it doesn't answer my question.

Can anyone explain why the difference?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I avoid having Python class data shared among instances?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1680528/how-do-i-avoid-having-python-class-data-shared-among-instances)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're not doing the same thing in your second example.  In you first example, you are assigning `f1.a` a new value:

```
f1.a = 5
```

In your second example, you are simply extending a list:

```
f1.a.append(5)
```

This doesn't change what `f1.a` is pointing to.  If you were instead to do this:

```
f1.a = [5]
```

You would find that this behaves the same as your first example.

But consider this example:

```
>>> f1=Foo()
>>> f2=Foo()
>>> Foo.a = 5
>>> f1.a
5
>>> f2.a
5
```

In this example, we're actually changing the value of the *class* attribute,
and the change is visible in all instances of the class.  When you
type:

```
f1.a = 5
```

You're overriding the *class* attribute with an *instance* attribute.

Comment: "You're overriding the class attribute with an instance attribute." I don't think so. The class attribute remains untouched. In the code of user 11869, the attribute **a** is CREATED in the namspace of **f1** by the instruction ``f1.a = 5`` , because this attribute wasn't existing before, as it is shown in my answer using **\_\_dict__**

Answer (score 10):

Python's class attributes and object attributes are stored in separate [dictionaries](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries).  For the object `f1`, these can be accessed via, respectively, `f1.__class__.__dict__` and `f1.__dict__`.  Executing `print f1.__class__ is Foo` will output `True`.

When you reference the attribute of an object, Python first tries to look it up in the object dictionary.  If it does not find it there, it checks the class dictionary (and so on up the inheritance heirarchy).

When you assign to `f1.a`, you are adding an entry to the object dictionary for `f1`.  Subsequent lookups of `f1.a` will find that entry.  Lookups of `f2.a` will still find the class attribute — the entry in the class attribute dictionary.

You can cause the value of `f1.a` to revert to `1` by deleting it:

```
del f1.a
```

This will remove the entry for `a` in the object dictionary of `f1`, and subsequent lookups will continue on to the class dictionary.  So, afterwards, `print f1.a` will output 1.

Comment: I think this answer is more elaborate

Comment: @Yuncy I think the same

Answer (score 7):

```
>>> class Foo:
...     a=1
... 
>>> f1=Foo()
>>> f2=Foo()
>>> f1.a    # no instance attribute here in f1, so look up class attribute in Foo
1
>>> f1.a=5  # create new instance attribute in f1
>>> f1.a    # instance attribute here. Great, let's use this.
5
>>> f2.a    # no instance attribute in f2, look up class attribute in Foo
1
>>>
>>> class Foo:
...     a=[]
... 
>>> f1=Foo()
>>> f2=Foo()
>>> f1.a            # no instance attribute - look up class attribute in Foo
[]
>>> f1.a.append(5)  # no instance attribute, modify class attribute in-place
>>> f1.a            # no instance attribute - look up class attribute in Foo
[5]
>>> f2.a            # same here
[5]
```

Answer (score 4):

My advice: to understand such cases, do tests using `id`, and `__dict__` too :

```
class Foo:
    a=1

# Foo.a == 1
# id(Foo.a) == 10021840
# Foo.__dict__ == {'a': 1, '__module__': '__main__', '__doc__': None}


f1 = Foo()

# f1.a == 1
# id(f1.a) == 10021840
# f1.__dict__ == {}

f2 = Foo()

# f2.a == 1
# id(f2.a) == 10021840
# f2.__dict__ == {}

f1.a = 5

# f1.a == 5
# id(f1.a) == 10021792
# f1.__dict__ == {'a': 5}

# f2.a == 1
# id(f2.a) == 10021840
# f2.__dict__ == {}
```

This shows that as long as the instruction `f1.a = 5` has not been executed, the instance `f1` doesn't have a personal attribute `a`.

Then, why does the instruction `print f1.a` executed before `f1.a = 5` produce `1`?
That's because:

> A class instance has a namespace implemented as a dictionary which is
>   the first place in which attribute references are searched. When an
>   attribute is not found there, and the instance’s class has an
>   attribute by that name, the search continues with the class
>   attributes.
>
> http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#the-standard-type-hierarchy

Answer (score 0):

What happens is the following:

When you instantiate a new object `f1 = Foo()`, it does not have any attributes of its own. Whenever you try to access for example `f1.a`, you get redirected to the class’s `Foo.a`:

```
print f1.__dict__
{}

print f1.a
1
```

However, if you *set*  `f1.a = 5`, the instance gets a new attribute of that value:

```
print f1.__dict__
{'a': 5}
```

The class definition is untouched by this, as are any other instances.

In the second example, you do not reassign anything. With `append` you are only using that very same list which was defined in the class. Therefore, your instance still refers to that list, as do all other instances.

Comment: Same as the answer I was about to type. I'd just add that the reason it "works" with a list is because in that case the object is [mutable](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-mutable). Since all instances refer to the same object, modifications to that object are seen by them all.

Comment: @Debilski: new instances actually often have attributes of their own (the `f1.__dict__` that you write in your answer is one of them, as can be see be comparing `id(Foo.a)` and `id(f1.a)`).

Answer (score 0):

When you assign an attribute in python, it doesn't matter where that attribute might already be defined, the new assignment is always applied to the object assigned to.  When you say

```
>>> f1.a=5
```

The object that has the attribute here is the instance, so it's the instance that gets the new value.