# Create an instance in a class in python

Tags: python, class, methods

I am trying to create a new instance of a class in Python. I tried the solution here:
[Instances in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12457259/instances-in-python)

But it didn't work. So, my main class I have

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    Tim = Person
    movement = Person.walk()
```

Where "Person" is the name of the class that I want to create and instance of. It has methods that I want to use.

I keep getting this error though:

```
Undefined Variable:Person
```

I also tried declaring the class instance within the actual metho, not init, but I got the same error.

Any suggestions are welcome. thanks

Comment: That's an odd error. Did you import/define `Person` class properly? Plus you instantiate class by calling it: `Person()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correction: please use bracket after class if you want to create an instance of that class and use that instance to call the method inside the class.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    Tim = Person()
    movement = Tim.walk()
```

OR but less recommended

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    movement = Person().walk()
```

Comment: I am getting the same error. Do the classes have to be in the same file? Maybe that is what is wrong? They are in the same directory, just different files

Comment: @Blossom96 You have to `import` the `Person` class before you use it.

Comment: Yes if the class is not in the same file, then you need to import the module i.e file, where the class is defined.

Comment: After you import the module, you can use the class as `module.Class()`

Comment: Same thing... unresolved import. I am writing import Person at the top of my file and I have made sure that init is at the bottom of my file

Comment: Could you please read this http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html about how to import module.

Comment: @Blossom96 If your `Person` class is in `foo.py` then use `from foo import Person`

Comment: oh okay thanks, I will. @sjcipher thanks, your answer was right. I just copied the classes into the same file to double check. I'll vote it up when the time period is up

Answer (score 2):

You just need to add some parenthesis:

```
Tim = Person()
```

This tells python to access the constructor.

The code you provided though tells me you may not have a class `Person` defined.  Your code should have a `class Person` defined.

```
class Person:
    def walk(self):
        print "I'm walking!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Time = Person
    movement = Person.walk()
    print movement
```

or you need a call to `import` the `class Person`

```
from my_other_python_file import Person

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Time = Person
    movement = Person.walk()
    print movement
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have parenthesis to call the constructor.

```
Tim = Person()
```

As you have it now, `Tim = Person` is interpreted as assign `Tim` the value of the variable `Person` which hasn't been defined.