# What's the difference between class attributes and data attributes in python

Tags: python, class, attributes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Python: Difference between class and instance attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/207000/python-difference-between-class-and-instance-attributes)

```
class a:
    m = 1
    def __init__(self):
        self.n = 2
```

According to the book I am reading, `m` is called class attributes and `n` is called data attributes, but what's the difference between them?

It seems that the operations of them is nearly same. The only difference I can tell is one is in the function `__init__` and another isn't.

Comment: If the difference between a class attribute and an instance attribute isn't immediately obvious, then you need to go back and read the explanation of the difference between a class and an instance again. A class attribute is one that is part of the class. An instance attribute is one that is part of the instance.

Comment: For me what's rather surprising is why does the book call instance attributes, usually simply called attributes, "data" attributes? It seems like it's mixing two different things. I was under the impression that "data" meant to emphasize values meant to be contansts (at a given version) from a design perspective.

Answer (score -1):

This is essentially a duplicate of this question which has an example of the difference.

[Python: Difference between class and instance attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/207000/python-difference-between-class-and-instance-attributes)