# Python and its references

Tags: python

I am currently wondering why this modest piece of code has an output I'm not expecting:

```
class Product(object):
    price = 0

    def __init__(self, tmp_price):
        self.price = tmp_price

class Market(object):
    products = []

    def __init__(self):
        self.products.append(Product(10))

a = Market()
b = Market()

print a.products[0]
print b.products[0]
print len(a.products)
```

Indeed, I get some output like:

```
<__main__.Product object at 0x7fe5899e46d0>
<__main__.Product object at 0x7fe5899e46d0>
2
```

Does anyone have an explanation? I guess it has something to do with python's way to handle references and all but...

Answer (score 5):

The problem is in this part of your code:

```
class Market(object):
    products = []  # products belongs to the class and is shared by all instances!
    def __init__(self):
        self.products.append(Product(10)) # appending to the 'products' class atribute
```

The `products` attribute belongs to the class and is *shared* by all instances.  Class attributes are accessible from all instances of the class.  When you reference products from self (`self.products`), Python does not find `products` belonging to the instance, so then it looks in to see if `products` can be found in the class.

What you really want is this:

```
class Market(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.products = []  # products belongs to the instance
        self.products.append(Product(10))
```

See also [Python: Difference between class and instance attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/207000/python-difference-between-class-and-instance-attributes)

Answer (score 4):

You are referencing static class variables.

[Static class variables in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68645/static-class-variables-in-python)
THere is lots of information about it online!

`Market.products[0]` is the actual value.

This is not the same as an instance variable as you found out. http://legacy.python.org/doc/essays/ppt/acm-ws/sld051.htm

Answer (score 3):

It's because you're printing the objects reference, not the value of its field;

Try changing

```
print a.products[0]
print b.products[0]
```

to

```
print a.products[0].price
print b.products[0].price
```

Comment: Actually my point was that both a.products[0] and b.products[0] are the same, they are the same reference.

Comment: Ahh yes, good point - it's because your self.products field is static. a.products == b.products will be True.  dm03514 has the link to the info in his answer.

Comment: @Russ C: I think "static" is the wrong word here because `Market.products` made to refer to a different object.  I would prefer "class attribute" or "shared".

Comment: Fair enough, I'm just using the C# definition of static out of habit rather then anything else.

Answer (score 2):

Because in Market **init**, self.products is using Market class member products, it shared between all Market's instance.

Answer (score 1):

That is the default way Python implements the **_*str*_**() function:

```
<module-name>.<class-name> <type> at <memory-address>
```

If you don't like this representation, you can always give your own implementation of **_*str*_**(). The memory-addresses are provided as a way for you to check if two variables actually point to the same item.