# Perform action when instance name is invoked in IDLE

Tags: python, python-2.7

So let's say you have something like this:

```
Class Person:
    height = """6' 0"""
```

and

```
Henry = Person
```

What do I have to define in the class to do `Henry` and get `'6' 0"'` and not something like `<class __main__.Person 0x00012040>`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you need to [**instantiate** the class](http://www.diveintopython.net/object_oriented_framework/defining_classes.html).

```
Henry = Person()
```

Then, you need to define the [`__repr__()` method](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__).

```
Class Person:
    def __repr__(self):
        return self.height
```

And finally, you need to make it an [instance attribute, not a class attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/207000/python-difference-between-class-and-instance-attributes).

```
Class Person:
    def __init__(self):
        self.height = "6' 0\""
```

Comment: The OP could just do `Person.height` but yes, it is most likely what they're asking for, and nicely explained so +1 from me

Comment: Oh right, `Henry = Person` just sets Henry **equal** to the Person class, not instantiating it. Thank you!