# append in a list causing value overwrite

Tags: python

I am facing a peculiar problem. I will describe in brief bellow
Suppose i have this piece of code -

```
class MyClass:

   __postBodies = []
    .
    .
    .
for the_file in os.listdir("/dir/path/to/file"):
      file_path = os.path.join(folder, the_file)
      params = self.__parseFileAsText(str(file_path)) #reads the file and gets some parsed data back
      dictData = {'file':str(file_path), 'body':params}
      self.__postBodies.append(dictData)
      print self.__postBodies
      dictData = None
      params = None
```

Problem is, when i print the params and the dictData everytime for different files it has different values (the right thing), but as soon as the append occurs, and I print __postBodies a strange thing happens. If there are thee files, suppose A,B,C, then

> first time __postBodies has the content = [{'body':{A dict with some
>   data related to file A}, 'file':'path/of/A'}]
>
> second time it becomes = [{'body':{A dict with some data relaed to
>   file B}, 'file':'path/of/A'}, {'body':{A dict with some data relaed to
>   file B}, 'file':'path/of/B'}]
>
> AND third time = [{'body':{A dict with some data relaed to file C},
>   'file':'path/of/A'}, {'body':{A dict with some data relaed to file C},
>   'file':'path/of/B'}, {'body':{A dict with some data relaed to file C},
>   'file':'path/of/C'}]

So, you see the 'file' key is working very fine. Just strangely the 'body' key is getting overwritten for all the entries with the one last appended.

Am i making any mistake? is there something i have to? Please point me to a direction.

Sorry if I am not very clear.

EDIT ------------------------

The return from self.__parseFileAsText(str(file_path)) call is a dict that I am inserting as 'body' in the dictData.

EDIT2 ----------------------------

as you asked, this is the code, but i have checked that params = self.__parseFileAsText(str(file_path)) call is returning a diff dict everytime.

```
def __parseFileAsText(self, fileName):

        i = 0
        tempParam = StaticConfig.PASTE_PARAMS

        tempParam[StaticConfig.KEY_PASTE_PARAM_NAME] = ""
        tempParam[StaticConfig.KEY_PASTE_PARAM_PASTEFORMAT] = "text"
        tempParam[StaticConfig.KEY_PASTE_PARAM_EXPIREDATE] = "N"
        tempParam[StaticConfig.KEY_PASTE_PARAM_PRIVATE] = ""
        tempParam[StaticConfig.KEY_PASTE_PARAM_USER] = ""
        tempParam[StaticConfig.KEY_PASTE_PARAM_DEVKEY] = ""
        tempParam[StaticConfig.KEY_PASTE_FORMAT_PASTECODE] = ""

        for line in fileinput.input([fileName]):
            temp = str(line)
            temp2 = temp.strip()
            if i == 0:              
                postValues = temp2.split("|||")

                if int(postValues[(len(postValues) - 1)]) == 0 or int(postValues[(len(postValues) - 1)]) == 2:
                    tempParam[StaticConfig.KEY_PASTE_PARAM_NAME] = str(postValues[0])

                    if str(postValues[1]) == '':                                        
                        tempParam[StaticConfig.KEY_PASTE_PARAM_PASTEFORMAT] = 'text'
                    else:
                        tempParam[StaticConfig.KEY_PASTE_PARAM_PASTEFORMAT] = postValues[1]

                    if str(postValues[2]) != "N":
                        tempParam[StaticConfig.KEY_PASTE_PARAM_EXPIREDATE] = str(postValues[2])

                    tempParam[StaticConfig.KEY_PASTE_PARAM_PRIVATE] = str(postValues[3])
                    tempParam[StaticConfig.KEY_PASTE_PARAM_USER] = StaticConfig.API_USER_KEY
                    tempParam[StaticConfig.KEY_PASTE_PARAM_DEVKEY] = StaticConfig.API_KEY

                else:
                    tempParam[StaticConfig.KEY_PASTE_PARAM_USER] = StaticConfig.API_USER_KEY
                    tempParam[StaticConfig.KEY_PASTE_PARAM_DEVKEY] = StaticConfig.API_KEY
                i = i+1
            else:
                if tempParam[StaticConfig.KEY_PASTE_FORMAT_PASTECODE] != "" :           
                    tempParam[StaticConfig.KEY_PASTE_FORMAT_PASTECODE] = str(tempParam[StaticConfig.KEY_PASTE_FORMAT_PASTECODE])+"\n"+temp2
                else:
                    tempParam[StaticConfig.KEY_PASTE_FORMAT_PASTECODE] = temp2

        return tempParam
```

Comment: Can you show the code of `self.__parseFileAsText`? It looks like the same dictionary is being reused which leads to the value of the `'body'` key being altered each time.

Comment: Do yourself a favor, don't use double-underscore names.  A single underscore is enough to indicate that others shouldn't use it.

Comment: Thanks Ned. will keep in mind :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are likely returning the same dictionary with every call to `MyClass.__parseFileAsText()`, a couple of common ways this might be happening:

- `__parseFileAsText()` accepts a [mutable default argument](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1132941/505154) (the dict that you eventually return)
- You modify an attribute of the class or instance and return that instead of creating a new one each time

Making sure that you are creating a new dictionary on each call to `__parseFileAsText()` should fix this problem.

**Edit:** Based on your updated question with the code for `__parseFileAsText()`, your issue is that you are reusing the same dictionary on each call:

```
tempParam = StaticConfig.PASTE_PARAMS
...
return tempParam
```

On each call you are modifying `StaticConfig.PASTE_PARAMS`, and the end result is that all of the body dictionaries in your list are actually references to `StaticConfig.PASTE_PARAMS`.  Depending on what `StaticConfig.PASTE_PARAMS` is, you should change that top line to one of the following:

```
# StaticConfig.PASTE_PARAMS is an empty dict
tempParam = {}

# All values in StaticConfig.PASTE_PARAMS are immutable
tempParam = dict(StaticConfig.PASTE_PARAMS)
```

If any values in `StaticConfig.PASTE_PARAMS` are mutable, you could use [`copy.deepcopy`](http://docs.python.org/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy) but it would be better to populate `tempParam` with those default values on your own.

Comment: You are right. so silly of me. anyway, it is done now. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

What if `__postBodies` wasn't a class attribute, as it is defined now, but just an instance attribute?

Comment: i think in case of mine it is fine to be a class attribute, as i am using only one reference to MyClass elsewhere to call the function which does the job. but you are right for cases where this is not the condition. a good reference can be found here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/207000/python-difference-between-class-and-instance-attributes