# Python method doesn't run in class

Tags: python

I am new to Python and can't seem to figure out why the .getRow method doesn't run.  I created a DBMain class in dbMain.py and I am using pyTest.py to create the DBMain object to run getRow.  When I run the debugger in Eclipse and DBMain's constructor does run but but when the getRow method is call nothing happens.

pyTest.py

```
import dbMain

def main():
    db = dbMain.DbMain()
    db.getRow()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

dbMain.py

```
#@PydevCodeAnalysisIgnore
import pyodbc
class DbMain(object):
    cncx = ''
    def __init__(self):
        cnxn = pyodbc.connect(driver='{SQL Server}', 
                              server='server', 
                              database='database', 
                              uid='name', 
                              pwd='pwd')

    def getRow(): 
        cursor = cnxn.cursor()
        cursor.execute("select user_id, user_name from users")
        row = cursor.fetchone()
        return row
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You do not *return* anything from `getRow`. Maybe you want to include something like

   ```
   ...
   return row
   ```
2. Your `getRow()` method is not bound to the class. The signature for an instance method should look something like `getRow(self)` - the first parameter is the instance, which is received explicitly (but passed implicitly, when you call `someinstance.method()`).

To have something functional, you maybe should alter your dbMain to something like this:

```
#@PydevCodeAnalysisIgnore
import pyodbc
class DbMain(object):
    def __init__(self):
        # make cnxn an attribute of the instance
        self.cnxn = pyodbc.connect(driver='{SQL Server}', server='server', 
            database='database', uid='name', pwd='pwd')

    # receive `self` explicitly
    def getRow(self): 
        cursor = self.cnxn.cursor()
        cursor.execute("select user_id, user_name from users")
        row = cursor.fetchone()
        # actually return something
        return row
```

Further reading:

- [Python: Difference between class and instance attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/207000/python-difference-between-class-and-instance-attributes)

Comment: Isn't he also missing `getRow(self)`?

Comment: I had return row with the method and the method still did not run

Comment: @Chad: does your current code have `getRow(self)` and is still not running?

Comment: After adding 'self' the method now runs, Thanks!