# What is the difference between declaring data attributes inside or outside __init__

Tags: python, attributes, initialization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Python: Difference between class and instance attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/207000/python-difference-between-class-and-instance-attributes)

I'm trying to get my head around OOP in Python and I'm a bit confused when it comes to declare variables within a class. Should I declare them inside of the `__init__` procedure or outside it? What's the difference?

The following code works just fine:

```
# Declaring variables within __init__
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        country = ""
        city = ""
    def information(self):
        print "Hi! I'm from %s, (%s)"%(self.city,self.country)

me = MyClass()
me.country = "Spain"
me.city = "Barcelona"
me.information()
```

But declaring the variables outside of the `__init__` procedure also works:

```
# Declaring variables outside of __init__
class MyClass:
    country = ""
    city = ""
    def information(self):
        print "Hi! I'm from %s, (%s)"%(self.city,self.country)

me = MyClass()
me.country = "Spain"
me.city = "Barcelona"
me.information()
```

Comment: This question appears to also be confusing instance attributes and method local variables.

Comment: **There is no such thing as a *variable declaration* in python!**
Variables are only assigned to/initialized(*binded* is the correct term).
There is no distinction between declaration and initialization.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In your first example you are defining *instance attributes*. In the second, *class attributes*.

Class attributes are shared between all instances of that class, where as instance attributes are "owned" by that particular instance.

**Difference by example**

To understand the differences let's use an example.

We'll define a class with instance attributes:

```
class MyClassOne:
    def __init__(self):
        self.country = "Spain"
        self.city = "Barcelona"
        self.things = []
```

And one with class attributes:

```
class MyClassTwo:
    country = "Spain"
    city = "Barcelona"
    things = []
```

And a function that prints out information about one of these objects:

```
def information(obj):
    print "I'm from {0}, ({1}). I own: {2}".format(
                obj.city, obj.country, ','.join(obj.things))
```

Let's create 2 `MyClassOne` objects and change one to be Milan, and give Milan "something":

```
foo1 = MyClassOne()
bar1 = MyClassOne()

foo1.city = "Milan"
foo1.country = "Italy"
foo1.things.append("Something")
```

When we call `information()` on the `foo1` and `bar1` we get the values you'd expect:

```
>>> information(foo1)
I'm from Milan, (Italy). I own: Something

>>> information(bar1)
I'm from Barcelona, (Spain). I own:
```

However, if we were to do exactly the same thing, but using instances of `MyClassTwo` you'll see that the class attributes are shared between instances.

```
foo2 = MyClassTwo()
bar2 = MyClassTwo()

foo2.city = "Milan"
foo2.country = "Italy"
foo2.things.append("Something")
```

And then call `information()`...

```
>>> information(foo2)
I'm from Milan, (Italy). I own: Something
>>> information(bar2)
I'm from Barcelona, (Spain). I own: Something
```

So as you can see - `things` is being shared between the instances. `things` is a reference to a list that each instance has access to. So if you append to things from any instance that same list will be seen by all other instances.

The reason you don't see this behaviour in the string variables is because you are actually assigning a new variable to an instance. In this case that reference is "owned" by the instance and not shared at the class level. To illustrate let's assign a new list to things for `bar2`:

```
bar2.things = []
```

This results in:

```
>>> information(foo2)
I'm from Milan, (Italy). I own: Something
>>> information(bar2)
I'm from Barcelona, (Spain). I own:
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It makes perfect sense now. I suppose that I got confused because I was using an immutable type.

Answer (score 5):

You're two versions of the code are very different.  In python, you have 2 distinct entities:  *classes* and *class instances*.  An instance is what is created when you do:

```
new_instance = my_class()
```

You can bind attributes to an instance within `__init__` via `self` (`self` is the new instance).

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.country = ""  #every instance will have a `country` attribute initialized to ""
```

There's nothing terribly special about `self` and `__init__`.  `self` is the customary name that is used to represent the instance that gets passed to *every method* (by default).

```
a.method()  #-> Inside the class where `method` is defined, `a` gets passed in as `self`
```

The only thing special here is that `__init__` gets called when the class is constructed:

```
a = MyClass()  #implicitly calls `__init__`
```

You can also bind attributes to the class (putting it outside `__init__`):

```
class MyClass(object):
    country = ""  #This attribute is a class attribute.
```

At any point, you can bind a new attribute to an instance simply by:

```
my_instance = MyClass()
my_instance.attribute = something
```

Or a new attribute to a class via:

```
MyClass.attribute = something
```

Now it gets interesting.  If an instance doesn't have a requested attribute, then python looks at the class for the attribute and returns it (if it is there).  So, class attributes are a way for all instances of a class to share a piece of data.

Consider:

```
def MyClass(object):
    cls_attr = []
    def __init__(self):
        self.inst_attr = []

a = MyClass()
a.inst_attr.append('a added this')
a.cls_attr.append('a added this to class')
b = MyClass()
print (b.inst_attr) # []  <- empty list, changes to `a` don't affect this.
print (b.cls_attr) # ['a added this to class'] <- Stuff added by `a`!
print (a.inst_attr) #['a added this']
```

Comment: Might be useful to underline that `__init__` has absolutely nothing special. You can add instance attributes in every method, or even outside the class code(as the Op is doing even if I don't know if he knows that).

Comment: @Bakuriu -- Updated.  Maybe that will be more clear now?

Comment: Nice, but I thing should also make more clear that class attributes are shared across instances and that may cause problems for someone that doesn't understand this.

Answer (score 0):

When you define a variable in class scope (outside any method), it becomes a class attribute.  When you define a value in method scope, it becomes a method local variable.  If you assign a value to an attribute of `self` (or any other label referencing an object), it becomes (or modifies) an instance attribute.