# difference between <class name>. <var name> and self.<var name> in a python class

Tags: python, class

I was wondering what was the difference between the Foo.var= user input and self.var= userinput in the 2 classes.

```
class foo():
    var=None

    def __init__(self,userinput):
        foo.var=userinput


class bar():
    var=None

    def __init__(self,userinput):
        self.var=userinput
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`foo` refers to the *class*, `self` refers to the *object*.

Class members are a property of the class (and thus are shared between all objects of that class), while instance members are a property of the specific object, so a change to an instance member affects only the given object.

When you operate on an object, the members it has are a merge of the *class* members and the *instance* members. When two members with the same name are defined, the instance members have the priority.

Thus:

- `bar` sets an instance variable; that change has effect only on the current instance, so if you do:

  ```
  b=bar(10)
  c=bar(20)
  ```

  you'll see that `c.var` is `20` and `b.var` is `10`; nothing strange here;
- `foo` sets a class variable, which is common to all the instances; so, if you do:

  ```
  f=foo(10)
  g=foo(20)
  ```

  you'll see that both `f.var` and `g.var` will be `20`, because they both actually refer to `foo.var`, that was last set to `20` in `g`'s constructor;
- on the other hand, instance variables shadow class variables; so, if you do

  ```
  f=foo(10)
  g=foo(20)
  f.var=30
  ```

  you'll have `g.var==foo.var==20`, but `f.var==30`, since now `f.var` refers to the *instance variable* f.var; *but*, if you do

  ```
  del f.var
  ```

  now the instance (`f`'s) attribute `var` no longer exists, and thus `f.var` refers again to the *class attribute* `var` (thus `f.var==g.var==foo.var==20`).

---

Long story short: normally you'll want to use `self.var` (i.e. instance members); `classname.var` is only for sharing stuff between all instances of a given class.

Comment: perfect, that explains everything. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to point to an existing post which explains the difference perfectly in my opinion.

[Python: Difference between class and instance attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/207000/python-difference-between-class-and-instance-attributes)

Answer (score 0):

Yes,

In the first instance you are setting the variable for all instances of `foo` this is because it is a `class` variable.

In the second case you are only setting the variable for that instance of `foo`.

For Example:

```
class pie():
    def __init__(self, j):
        pie.var = "pies" + str(j)
        print (self.var)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.var

a = pie(1)
b = pie(2)

print (a)
print (b)
```