# Attribute created in one method doesn't exist in other method

Tags: python, class, attributes

Here I have an attribute 'a', which is defined in first class method and should be changed in second.
When calling them in order, this message appears:

> AttributeError: 'Class' object has no attribute 'a'

The only way I've found - define 'a' again in second method, but in real code it has long inheritance and app will be messed.
Why doesn't it work? Isn't *self.a* equal to *Class.a*?

```
class Class(object):
    def method_1(self):
        self.a = 1
    def method_2(self):
        self.a += 1

Class().method_1()
Class().method_2()
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Short answer, no. The problem with your code is that each time you create a new instance.

**Edit**: As abarnert mentions below, there is a big difference between `Class.a` and `c.a`. Instance attributes (the second case) belong to each specific object, whereas class attributes belong to the class. Look at abarnert's comment below or the discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/207000/python-difference-between-class-and-instance-attributes) for more info.

Your code is equivalent to

```
c1 = Class()
c1.method_1()  # defines c1.a (an instance attribute)
c2 = Class()
c2.method_2()  # c2.a undefined (the c2 instance doesn't have the attribute)
```

You probably want to do somthing like

```
c = Class()
c.method_1()  # c.a = 1
c.method_2()  # c.a = 2
print "c.a is %d" % c.a  # prints "c.a is 2"
```

Or probably even better would be to initialize `c` with an `a` attribute

```
class Class:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 1  # all instances will have their own a attribute
```

Comment: Great answer… but it's probably worth explaining that `self.a` is not equal to `Class.a`, instead of just flatly saying "no"). `self.a` is an _instance attribute_: each `Class` instance has its own copy. `Class.a` is a _class attribute_: the class itself has a single copy, no matter how many instances there are (sort of like a static member in C++ and related languages). And If you don't know why you'd want a class attribute, you don't want one.

Answer (score 3):

A *newly-created* instance of `Class` has no attribute `a` when you do `instance_of_class.method_2()` without calling `method_1`, as in your example.

Consider this slightly altered version of your code:

```
class CreateNewClassInstance(object):
    def create_a(self):
        self.a = 1
    def add_one_to_a(self):
        self.a += 1

CreateNewClassInstance().create_a()
CreateNewClassInstance().add_one_to_a()
```

Each time you call `Class()` (or `CreateNewClassInstance()`) you create a *new* object, with its own attribute `a`.  Until you initialize `a`, you don't have an attribute with that name.

Most of the time this isn't an issue - however, `+=` will attempt to load `self.a` before adding one to it - which is what is causing your `AttributeError` in this case.