# When to use __init__ when creating a class

Tags: python, class

After using Django for a while, I got use to using classes without `def __init__(self): ...` when declaring variables. I used to declare my variables in the `__init__` function, I now realize that there are cases where don't need to, I'm just unclear on when to use it or not. It seems there is a problem when trying to pass a class to a variable, should I use **init** in these cases?

I know I could just use `__init__` for all cases, but it just makes my short classes like cleaner without it, so I would like to know when I can and cannot use it.

example:

```
class BaseScraper(object):
    # whithout __init__, passing Site() to site wont work.
    # site = Site()
    # parser = None

    def __init__(self):
        self.site = Site()
        self.parser = None 


class Site(object):
    # no trouble declaring url as a str
    url = ""

    def set(self, url):
        self.url = url

    def get(self):
        return self.url



if __name__ == "__main__":
    scraper = BaseScraper()

    scraper.site.set('http://www.google.com')   
    print scraper.site.get()
```

Comment: Django doesn't really represent Python. Django model fields are class-level attributes, they are in fact actual objects that aren't at all "holders" for your data, and they serve as medatada that the base `Model`'s `__init__()` method (or some other part of that wad of code) uses to automagically create instance-level attributes and do a bunch of other stuff. Python doesn't normally work that way.

Comment: When initialising instance data, you should do so in `__init__` unless you know what you're doing. (That class-level attributes kinda sorta act like they're default values for instance attributes is a bit of a hack with a bunch of caveats.)

Comment: that's pretty interesting, thanks for explaing

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Attributes declared in the class are owned by the class rather than by individual instances of the class.  In your `site` example, `url` is no more a property of individual Site objects than `set` or `get` are.  For this kind of example, you want instance data - which you can initialize in `__init__`.

[Python: Difference between class and instance attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/207000/python-difference-between-class-and-instance-attributes) has a good discussion of the differences.

Answer (score 1):

This fails because `Site` class is not defined yet.
And (as  @Peter DeGlopper) said, there is a big difference between class variables and instance variables.

```
class BaseScraper(object):
    # This fails!
    site = Site()
    parser = None


class Site(object):
    # no trouble declaring url as a str
    url = ""

    def set(self, url):
        self.url = url

    def get(self):
        return self.url
```

When the virtual machine compile a python module, read and compile everything in class declaration, but on method declaration (like `def __init__(...):`) only read this line, ignoring the method body.

Example:

```
class Foo(object):
    bar1 = "bar"
    foo1 = "foo"

    def __init__(self):
        self.bar2 = "BAZ"

foo = Foo #Put a class in a veriable? yes, you can.
foo.bar1 # returns "bar"
foo.foo1 # returns "foo"
foo.bar2 # fails!!!! This will be a instance variable, but doesn't exist yet

foo2 = Foo() # Here the __init__ is called
foo2.bar2 # returns "BAZ"
foo2.bar1 #Returns "bar" because all class variables are availables from instances
```

Hope this helps =)