# Unexpected behavior with simple tree class

Tags: python

I am writing a learning program in python, and I'm not getting the behavior I'm expecting.  I am attempting to create a really basic tree with a class called node.  Please don't punish me for having a crappy tree design, I'm just trying to learn the language.

Anyway, I'm expecting output like:

```
LEVEL1 0
LEVEL1 1
```

But, I'm getting

```
LEVEL1 0
LEVEL1 1
LEVEL1 0 ... LEVEL2 0
```

On the line where I do `leaves[0].addLeaf`  I really thought I would be calling a method of of one of the children leaves, but it appears that I am instead calling from the TOP leaf.  Please help me understand.

Don't be tricked by the name `traversePrint`.  Nothing is being traversed, not yet anyway :(

```
#!/usr/bin/python

class node:
    """Something that can act like like leaves of a tree"""
    leaves = []
    def __init__(self, data=""):
        self.data = data
    def addLeaf(self, newNode="new"):
        self.leaves.append(node(newNode))
    def printLeafs(self):
        for leaf in self.leaves:
            print leaf.data
    def getLeafs(self):
        return self.leaves
    def traversePrint(self):
        for leaf in self.leaves:
            print leaf.data
        #for leaf in self.leaves:
        #   leaf.traversePrint()

top = node("TOP")
top.addLeaf("LEVEL1 0")
top.addLeaf("LEVEL1 1")

leaves = top.getLeafs()
leaves[0].addLeaf("LEVEL1 0 ... LEVEL2 0")

top.traversePrint()
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! You've managed to get your code to display properly, which is a very good start! I've made some minor edits to your post to format it a little better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that right now, `leaves` is a **class-level** attribute. You want it to be an **instance-level** attribute, so that the list isn't shared between all the instances. See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/207000/python-difference-between-class-and-instance-attributes) for some details on the difference.

Luckily, making `leaves` an instance attribute is easy to do: remove the line `leaves = []` and instead, change your `__init__` method to include the line `self.leaves = []`.

```
def __init__(self, data=""):
    self.data = data
    self.leaves = [] # Create a new list to hold this instance's children!
```

---

To see more clearly what's going on in your original code, try editing your `addLeaf` method by adding `print([leaf.data for leaf in self.leaves])` after you add the leaf. In your original code, this will print out:

```
['LEVEL1 0']
['LEVEL1 0', 'LEVEL1 1']
['LEVEL1 0', 'LEVEL1 1', 'LEVEL1 0 ... LEVEL2 0']
```

Of course, you only want one leaf to be shown on the third printout, because you're accessing a different node, but instead you got all three! This is because when the list is at the class level, all the instances of `node` share the same `leaves` list. When you move the list initialization inside the `__init__` method, you see the expected results from your three `addLeaf` calls:

```
['LEVEL1 0']
['LEVEL1 0', 'LEVEL1 1']
['LEVEL1 0 ... LEVEL2 0']
```

Answer (score 3):

Because you define `leaves` at the class level, **all** instances of `node` share a single `leaves` list.  I doubt that's what you intended.  If you want each `node` to have its **own** `leaves` list, then move the assignment into `__init__` instead:

```
    # leaves = [] # REMOVE THIS LINE
    def __init__(self, data=""):
        self.data = data
        self.leaves = []  # ADD THIS LINE
```

Then the output is:

```
LEVEL1 0
LEVEL1 1
```

and adding:

```
leaves[0].traversePrint()
```

prints:

```
LEVEL1 0 ... LEVEL2 0
```

Clear?

Answer (score 2):

`leaves` is a class attribute so all `addLeaf` does is adds to that single attribute as all nodes are objects of class `node` (btw rename it to Node)

What you want is per node attribute leaves, hence add it as instance attribute i.e. in `__init__` add `self.leaves = []`