# Pygame, Python 2.7, AttributeError: type object 'newPlayer' has no attribute 'rect', but I declared a rect attribute

Tags: python-2.7, pygame, sprite, game-development, rect

So I'm making a player object in pygame, and I had a sprite loader load up the image, set the object to have that image, and get a rectangle object of it.

However, when I try to test it out in main I get this error

```
AttributeError: type object 'newPlayer' has no attribute 'rect'
```

But I have this line in my newPlayer class

```
self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
```

What is going on?  I have had near-identical code with other objects in the game, and they worked without issue.

Full code:

```
import pygame

# Define some colors
black    = (   0,   0,   0)
white    = ( 255, 255, 255)
red      = ( 255,   0,   0)

#initialize pygame
pygame.init()

#set the height and width of the screen
width = 800
height = 480

mainScreen = pygame.display.set_mode([width,height])

#A list of all of the sprites in the game
all_sprites_list = pygame.sprite.Group()


def sprite_sheet_load(colorKey, spriteLocX, spriteLocY, spriteSizeX, spriteSizeY, fileName):
    '''Purpose: to extract a sprite from a sprite sheet at the chosen location'''
    '''credit to SO user hammyThePig for original code'''

    sheet = pygame.image.load(fileName).convert() #loads up the sprite sheet. convert makes sure the pixel format is coherent
    sheet.set_colorkey(colorKey) #sets the color key

    sprite = sheet.subsurface(pygame.Rect(spriteLocX, spriteLocY, spriteSizeX, spriteSizeY)) #grabs the sprite at this location

    return sprite

class newPlayer(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    '''class that builds up the player'''
     #constructor function
    def __init__(self): #create a self variable to do stuff

        #call up the parent's constructor
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

        img = "mainCharacterFinal.png"

        #size of each sprite
        sprite_sizeX = 35
        sprite_sizeY = 37

        #List of images for different types of movement
        self.imagesLeft = []

        self.imagesRight = []

        self.imagesUp = []

        self.imagesDown = []

        #these two variables go and help reset the position variables of the sprites
        xInit = 35
        yInit = 37

        #inital positions of sprites on the sheet
        positionX = 0
        positionY = 0

        colorKey = white #colorKey to pass to the function

        self.imagesUp.append(sprite_sheet_load(black, positionX, positionY, sprite_sizeX, sprite_sizeY, img))


        #the best image to use by default is the one that has the player facing the screen.
        self.image=self.imagesUp[0]


        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

newplayer = newPlayer()
all_sprites_list.add(newplayer)
newPlayer.rect.x = 300
newPlayer.rect.y = 300

#a conditional for the loop that keeps the game running until the user Xes out
done = False

#clock for the screen updates
clock = pygame.time.Clock()


while done==False:
    for event in pygame.event.get(): #user did something
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT: #if the user hit the close button
                done=True

    mainScreen.fill(white)#makes the background white, and thus, the white part of the images will be invisible

    #draw the sprites
    all_sprites_list.draw(mainScreen)

    #limit the game to 20 fps
    clock.tick(20)

    #update the screen on the regular
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Please post the full traceback. We have to know which of the roughly 100 lines are causing the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to write

```
    newplayer
```

instead of newPlayer in the respective place. This is because rect is attribute of the instance of the class and not the class itself, when you try to write

```
    newPlayer.rect
```

you are trying to access the rect attribute of newPlayer class which is not there, so you have to write

```
    newplayer.rect
```

try

```
    newplayer.rect.x = 300
    newplayer.rect.y = 300
```

Check the follwoing link:-
[Python: Difference between class and instance attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/207000/python-difference-between-class-and-instance-attributes)

Comment: Ugh!!! I knew it was going to be some dumb typo/oversight, but I wasn't seeing it for whatever reason, and I needed a second set of eyes.

Comment: It can happen with even the best of programmers. You can accept the answer, if it solved the problem for you.

Comment: I was going to earlier, but it wanted me to wait a few minutes and I had another commitment at the time. Taken care of.