# Lambda function passing not desired self

Tags: python, class, oop, lambda

Look this code:

```
class MyClass_1():
    @staticmethod
    def method_1(func):
        return func(1, 2, 3)

class MyClass_2():
    my_func = lambda a,b,c : a*b*c # I need to call this method

    def method_2(self):
        result = MyClass_1.method_1(self.my_func)
        print(result)
```

My error:

> TypeError: () takes 3 positional arguments but 4 were given

I need to call the lambda function `my_func` in the same way as the code above, but a `self` is appearing from somewhere I don't know and causing this error.

What am I missing?

Comment: Do you understand why `def my_func(a,b,c): return a*b*c` wouldn't work? A lambda is just the same as using `def`, if you define it in a class you need to include the `self`.

Comment: Yeah.. that's a good thing to think about... wouldn't work even I make it static?

Comment: With `@staticmethod` it would work, with `@classmethod` you would need a `cls` first parameter. In all respects (except the function name shown in tracebacks) a lambda is neither more nor less than a one line function returning the same expression.

Comment: Thats very interesting. Nice information. Thanks!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `my_func` is a class attribute of `MyClass_2`, you should not be accessing it through `self` (an instance of the class).  Instead, you should be accessing it through the class directly:

```
result = MyClass_1.method_1(MyClass_2.my_func)
                            ^^^^^^^^^
```

Demo:

```
>>> class MyClass_1():
...     @staticmethod
...     def method_1(func):
...         return func(1, 2, 3)
...
>>> class MyClass_2():
...     my_func = lambda a,b,c : a*b*c # I need to call this method
...     def method_2(self):
...         result = MyClass_1.method_1(MyClass_2.my_func)
...         print(result)
...
>>> MyClass_2().method_2()
6
>>>
```

For more information, you can check out these sources:

- https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#class-definitions
- [Python: Difference between class and instance attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/207000/2555451)

Comment: Worked. But how/where `self` enter in this history?

Comment: When you call `my_func` on `self`, Python will implicitly pass a reference to the class instance as the first argument.  But `my_func` is a class attribute, which means it doesn't need/use this reference.  So, we call it from the class directly to avoid this.

Answer (score 3):

A `lambda` is just different syntax for defining a function object. Functions in class bodies are *always* bound and passed a `self` argument (as they are [descriptors](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html)).

Simply give your `lambda` that argument:

```
my_func = lambda self, a, b, c: a * b * c
```

The alternative would be for you to unwrap the method and pass in the plain function object:

```
result = MyClass_1.method_1(self.my_func.__func__)
```

or to wrap your `lambda` in a `staticmethod` object:

```
my_func = staticmethod(lambda a, b, c: a * b * c)
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to give your `lambda` a self argument.  Lambdas are just ordinary functions.  There is no difference between this:

```
class Foo():
    my_func = lambda a,b,c : a*b*c
```

and this

```
class Foo():
    def my_func(a, b, c):
        return a*b*c
```

In both cases, `my_func` is a method, and `self` will be passed if you call it on an instance.

Answer (score 1):

lambdas are small anonymous functions and can be written in the parameter list of a method directly. Assigning them to a variable is usually not desirable. A typical use of lambda here would be:

```
class MyClass_1():
    @staticmethod
    def method_1(func):
        return func(1, 2, 3)

class MyClass_2():

    def method_2(self):
        result = MyClass_1.method_1(lambda a,b,c: a*b*c)
        print(result)

MyClass_2().method_2()
```