# How should data attributes of a class be used as default arguments in methods of the class?

Tags: python, class, methods, arguments, self

Let's say I want to set the default value of an argument of a method of a class to the value of some data attribute of the class. What is an appropriate way to do this? Is there a way to do this using lambda functions?

Here is some example code:

```
class A(object):

    def __init__(
        self
        ):
        self._defaultReportText = "hello world"

    def report(
        self,
        text = self._defaultReportText
        ):
        return(text)
```

Obviously, the default value specification for the argument `text` of the method `report` does not work here because `self` is not defined at this point. How should I make this value available?

Comment: just note that `self._defaultReportText` [isn't a class attribute, but an instance attribute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/207000/python-difference-between-class-and-instance-attributes).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot set the default value at class definition time, since defaults are stored with the function object, so no instances are available yet to take the default *from*.

Instead, use a *sentinel*, a unique value that you can easily test for. Usually this is `None`:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._defaultReportText = "hello world"

    def report(self, text=None):
        if text is None:
            text = self._defaultReportText
        return text
```

If no `text` argument was supplied, it defaults to `None` and that can easily be tested for.

If `None` should be a possible value (e.g. you want to be able to use `A().report(None)` and that would behave differently from `A().report()`, then you'll have to pick a different sentinel. In that case use a unique instance of `object()` to test against:

```
_sentinel = object()


class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._defaultReportText = "hello world"

    def report(self, text=_sentinel):
        if text is _sentinel:
            text = self._defaultReportText
        return text
```

Comment: Thank you @Martijn-Pieters, your answers are always very insightful!

Comment: Thank you very much for your help on that. Your approach was explained very clearly. I liked your abstract approach to the sentinel.

Answer (score 7):

If I understood your question, I usually do it with:

```
def report(self, text = None):
    if text is None:
        text = self._defaultReportText
    return(text)
```

(Edit: changed `if not text` to `if text is None` after Warren Weckesser's suggestion.)

Answer (score -1):

An alternative to using a special value such as `None` is to use a class variable:

```
class A(object):
    _defaultReportText = "hello world"

    def report(self, text=_defaultReportText):
        return text
```

Comment: The default is still fixed in the function, changing `A._defaultReportText` will not change the function default. The code only works because `_defaultReportText` is still a *local* variable when the class body is executed.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - Yes, that's right, that's the desired effect. You don't want the function default changed anyway - the default is hard coded in both OP and your `__init__()`. OP doesn't require that it be mutable. I don't see that there is any practical difference? If I am misunderstanding your point, could you please explain in more detail?

Comment: To, the variable may be hardcoded in the `__init__` but it still can be changed. By using a sentinel the function automatically picks up that change.

Comment: There is no point in setting a class attribute here; you could just use `def report(self, text="hello world"):` with the exact same results, the value is bound to the function object (in `A.report.__defaults__`) either way.

Comment: (and I wasn't being clear, the attribute on the instance can be changed later on, regardless as to what the `__init__` method set it to).

Comment: @MartijnPieters - where is the requirement that it be mutable? It can be changed, but the OP has marked the variable private with a leading underscore to suggest that it's value _shouldn't_ be changed anyway.

Comment: No, the attribute is marked as *internal to the implementation*, that doesn't mean it shouldn't be changed, it shouldn't be relied upon by code outside of the API. That's something entirely different.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - Your point about just using the default argument directly in the function definition is valid. I was thinking that the default might be used in  multiple methods - making it a class attribute facilitates that (but there's no OP requirement for that). Thanks for the explanation.