# Class attribute won't change

Tags: python

```
class GameState:
    def __init__(self):
        '''initializes the players turn'''
        self._player_turn = 'BLACK'
    def change_player_white(self):
        self._player_turn = 'WHITE'
    def p_move(self):
        return self._player_turn
```

if I call

```
project41.GameState().change_player_white()
print(project41.GameState().p_move())
```

it still prints out 'BLACK'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each call to `GameState()` creates a new instance.  You created an instance, changed the player to white, and then discarded that player and created a new one on the following line.  Try this:

```
state = project41.GameState()
state.change_player_white()
print(state.p_move())
```

Incidentally, your `_player_turn` is not a class attribute, but an instance attribute.

Comment: Whats the difference between a class attribute and an instance attribute?

Comment: @dustinyourface: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/207000/python-difference-between-class-and-instance-attributes) and many other resources that can be found by googling.

Answer (score 1):

Each time you call `project41.GameState()` you are creating a *new* `GameState` object. Instead, what you may want is:

```
my_game = project41.GameState()
my_game.change_player_white()

print(my_game.p_move())
```

If you really want a variable that is shared by *all instances* of your class, do see the [Class and Instance Variables](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#class-and-instance-variables) section in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a new instance of a GameState object with each of your calls.