# write to file in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, export-to-csv

I might ask a stupid question. I just started learning Python.

I have a simple python script, which defined a class with two methods: `add_course` and `write_to_file`:

```
class School:
    courses=["Math","Physics","Chemical"]

    def __init__(self):
        return

    def add_course(self, course):
        if course not in self.course:
           self.course.append(course)

    def write_to_file():
        course_file = open('courses.csv', 'w+')
        wr = csv.writer(course_file, delimiter='\t')
        writer.writerow(self.courses)

// create a School instance
school = School()

// add course
school.add_course("test")
school.add_course("test2")
school.add_course("test")

// write course to file
school.write_to_file()
```

I run the above script, then, I open the courses.csv file, I don't see "test" and "test2", but I can see the courses "Math","Physics","Chemical" Why?

Comment: why downvote my question? Please give a reason, I don't understand, I probably asked stupid question, but I am pretty new in Python.

Comment: Define class variables to be shared by all methods in the class in the init method. I recommend finding a basic tutorial on python classes

Comment: @Dan, thanks, do you mean I should put `courses` list in init method?

Comment: yes just like the top-voted answer right now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently you have added courses as class-level attribute, but trying to access it as instance attribute, so you have to **move courses initialization** into `__init__` method as in code snippet below:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.courses = ["Math", "Physics", "Chemical"]
```

Also you have to modify `add_course` method to append item into `self.courses` and **not to `self.course`**:

```
def add_course(self, course):
        if course not in self.courses:
           self.courses.append(course)
```

See SO [Python: Difference between class and instance attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/207000/python-difference-between-class-and-instance-attributes) question  for more explanations of how and when each type of attributes shall be used.

Comment: Thank you very much for pointing out my problem. I appreciate it more than just downvote which left me like helpless seeing those negative votings.

Comment: @Leem.fin You are welcome! I hope answer would point you into right direction ) Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I found few mistakes in your code snippet, As you are new to Python, So thought of posting working code-

```
class School:
    courses=["Math","Physics","Chemical"]

    def __init__(self):
        return

    def add_course(self, course):
        if course not in self.courses:
           self.courses.append(course)

    def write_to_file(self):
        with open('courses.csv', 'w+') as course_file:
        wr = csv.writer(course_file, delimiter='\t')
        wr.writerow(self.courses)
```

My changes-

```
1. def write_to_file(self)
2.if course not in self.courses:
               self.courses.append(course)
3. wr.writerow(self.courses)
```