# Why does Python instance create attribute automatically?

Tags: python

```
class A:
    foo = 5
a = A()
a.foo =6
```

By writing `a.foo = 6`,

> we're creating an instance attribute `foo` that hides a class attribute `foo`([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26642476))

How do we know `a.foo` is the instance attribute not the class attribute? Why doesnt `a` use the class attribute? How to view the hidden class attribute of instance `a` (if possible, since it is only hidden, not erased)?

Even after reading several related answers on SO, this still puzzles me.

Second question:

```
print id(A.foo)
A.foo = 0
print id(A.foo)
```

Why does the id of `A.foo` change? It is the **same** class attribute pointing to different integers.

Comment: your second question could be in a standalone question (maybe has been answered?) and can be reduced to a simpler case: `a = 3`, `id(a)`, `a=5`, `id(a)`.

Comment: And, to provide a partial answer "How to view the hidden class attribute of instance `a`?" The attribute is not for instance `a`, is an attribute for _class_ `A` so you can view it through `A.foo`.