# list of objects python

Tags: python, python-object

I am trying to print a list of python objects that contain a list as a property and i am having some unexpected results:

here is my code:

```
class video(object):

    name = ''
    url = ''

class topic(object):

    topicName = ''
    listOfVideo = []

    def addVideo(self,videoToAdd):
        self.listOfVideo.append(videoToAdd)

    def getTopic(self):
        return self.topicName

    def getListOfVideo(self):
        return self.listOfVideo


topic1 = topic()
topic1.topicName = 'topic1'
video1 = video()
video1.name = 'VideoName1'
video1.url = 'VideoURL1'

video2 = video()
video2.name = 'VideoName2'
video2.url = 'VideoURL2'
topic1.addVideo(video1)
topic1.addVideo(video2)

topic2 = topic()
topic2.topicName = 'topic2'

video3 = video()
video3.name = 'VideoName3'
video3.url = 'VideoURL3'

video4 = video()
video4.name = 'VideoName4'
video4.url = 'VideoURL4'

topic2.addVideo(video3)
topic2.addVideo(video4)

topicsList = []
topicsList.append(topic1)
topicsList.append(topic2)

for topicCurrent in topicsList:
    print(topicCurrent.topicName)
    for video in topicCurrent.getListOfVideo():
        print(video.name)
        print(video.url)
```

What I ***expect*** to get is this:

> topic1
>
> VideoName1
>
> VideoURL1
>
> VideoName2
>
> VideoURL2
>
> topic2
>
> VideoName3
>
> VideoURL3
>
> VideoName4
>
> VideoURL4

but what I ***actually*** get is this:

> topic1
>
> VideoName1
>
> VideoURL1
>
> VideoName2
>
> VideoURL2
>
> VideoName3
>
> VideoURL3
>
> VideoName4
>
> VideoURL4
>
> topic2
>
> VideoName1
>
> VideoURL1
>
> VideoName2
>
> VideoURL2
>
> VideoName3
>
> VideoURL3
>
> VideoName4
>
> VideoURL4

Why? I want to iterate over my list of topics and print out each video in each topic, but for each topic it prints out all videos???

What is going on here?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/207000/python-difference-between-class-and-instance-attributes

Comment: You're creating class variables, not object variables. Add an `__init__` function.

Comment: Follow PEP8 to write python code..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have created `class variables` instead of `instance variables`, which are different for each instance object. Define your class as follows:

```
class topic(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.topicName = ''
        self.listOfVideo = []

    def addVideo(self,videoToAdd):
        self.listOfVideo.append(videoToAdd)

    def getTopic(self):
        return self.topicName

    def getListOfVideo(self):
        return self.listOfVideo
```

From [Python Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#class-and-instance-variables):

> Instance variables are for data unique to each instance and class
>   variables are for attributes and methods shared by all instances of
>   the class.

**EDIT:**

One more important thing to consider is that why only `listOfVideo` was common for all instances but not `topicName`. It is because `list`'s are mutable objects while `string`'s are immutable.

So any changes made to `listOfVideo` are common for all instances, i.e., they still refer to `listOfVideo` defined in the `topic` namespace.

However when you do `topic1.topicName = 'topic1'`, you create a new variable `topicName` within `topic1` namespace, which overrides the `topicName` found in `topic`(class) namespace. You can confirm it by printing the value `topic.topicName`, which you will find to be an empty string, i.e., `''`.

Comment: ahh. thanks. Apperntly i didn't know that my variables in my class were class variables. Now i know thanks!