# Python class instance issue

Tags: python, class, instance

```
class Numbers:
    data = []
    def read_from_row(self, row):
        row_list = list(row)
        for i in row_list:
            self.data.append(i)


list1 = ["15","16"]
list2 = ["17","18"]

instance = Numbers()
instance.read_from_row(list1)
print(instance.data)

instance = Numbers()
instance.read_from_row(list2)
print(instance.data)
```

Here is the piece of code. So in the beginning `instance` is the instance of the class `Numbers` and after reading the first list `print(instance.data)` naturally prints `['15', '16']`. But then I create new instance of class `Numbers` again still in the same variable `instance`, but after reading from the second list it still contains data from the first list for some reason. Outputting `['15', '16', '17', '18']`.

I'm sorry, I'm a beginner at python and after coding C/C++ for so long I can't understand why does this happen or what's expected behavior. I'm using Python 2.7.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Data is not an instance member but a class member.
All instances of numbers class "share" the same Data list.

See also here: [Python: Difference between class and instance attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/207000/python-difference-between-class-and-instance-attributes)

In order to do what you expect:

```
class Numbers:
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = []
    def readFromRow(self, row):
        self.data.extend(row)
```

Answer (score 2):

Instance variables are created in `__init__(..)`:

```
class Numbers(object):               # in Python 2.7 you should inherit from object
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = []

    def read_from_row(self, row):    # (python naming convention)
        self.data += row             # better way of appending to a list
```

Comment: You probably want to capitalize `numbers` if you're making a point of showing python naming conventions.

Comment: @pvg I was trying not to, but you're right and I've updated the code.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you step through the code in [pythontutor](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=class%20numbers%3A%0A%20%20%20%20Data%20%3D%20%5B%5D%0A%20%20%20%20def%20readFromRow(self,%20row%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20rList%20%3D%20list(row%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20for%20i%20in%20rList%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20self.Data.append(i%29%0A%0Ab1%20%3D%20numbers(%29%0Als%20%3D%20%5B%2215%22,%2216%22%5D%0Als2%20%3D%20%5B%2217%22,%2218%22%5D%0Ab1.readFromRow(ls%29%0Aprint(b1.Data%29%0Ab1%20%3D%20numbers(%29%0Ab1.readFromRow(ls2%29%0Aprint(b1.Data%29&cumulative=false&heapPrimitives=false&mode=edit&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=3&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false), notice that by putting `Data = []` in the class block it is shared between all instances.  (Other answers already show how to fix the issue, My goal is to give you a way to understand why the issue is happening)