# Are Class variables mutable?

Tags: python, class, oop, object, static

If I define a simple class

```
class someClass():
    var = 1

x = someClass()
someClass.var = 2
```

This will make `x.var` equal 2. This is confusing to be because normally
something akin to this like:

```
a = 1
b = a
a = 2
```

will leave b intact as `b==1`. So why is this not the same with class variables? Where is the difference? Can call all class variables mutable?
In a way the class variables work more like assigning a list to `a=[1]` and doing `a[0]=2`.

Basically the problem is how is `x.var` acessing someClass.var it must be something different then is used when two variables are set equal in python. What is happening?

Comment: now set `x.var = 3` and see what happens to `someClass.var`

Comment: I know but thats not the point

Comment: No, that *is* the point. Essentially, when you do `SomeClass.var` and `someInstance.var` **are not necessarily same thing**.

Comment: not at all this is about the fact that someClass.var = 2 changes x.var and how x.var is bound to the class variable compared to the normal functioning of variables in python

Comment: So why does someClass.var = 2 change x.var then?

Comment: `someClass.var` **does not** change `x.var`. Sometimes, an instance attribute *shadows* a class-attribute. That is the behavior you are seeing.

Comment: If `x` doesn't have its own `var` property, it uses the classes. When it does, the two become disentangled.

Comment: try it python2.7

Comment: I've tried it before. Many many times. As an aside, mutability isn't the issue here at all, actually. But ok, try this. `x = SomeClass(); x.var = 'foo'; SomeClass.var = 'bar'`. Did `SomeClass.var` change `x.var`?

Comment: Try `someclass.var = 1`, then `x.var` will be 1, then `x.var = 2`, `someclass.var` will not be 2, then `someclass.var = 3` and `x.var` will still be 2.

Comment: So again, the issue isn't *mutability*. The issue is *namespaces*. Usually, we think of namespaces as distinct, but in OOP, *instances can have access to their class namespace*

Comment: A picture is worth a thousand words: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34126204/476

Comment: @ C.Fe I know this but still the behavior works like this the other way around which is completely different from what happens if x.var was somehow defined by x.var = someClass.var. I do not see this addressed in the "Static class variables in Python " thread.

Comment: @pindakaas what do you mean exactly? `xvar = someClass.var` and then `x.var = 'something else'`, now did `someClass.var` change?

Comment: @pindakaas I was going to post [this](https://gist.github.com/juanarrivillaga/ab85dfcf70feff2d61a7a25175586aef) as an answer before this got targeted as a duplicate. Let me know if it helps clear things up a bit.

Comment: @deceze that's the best dupe target I think

Comment: @ juanpa.arrivillaga I think it does.

Comment: I think in the second duplicate "Python: Difference between class and instance attributes" , the quesion is not really a match but the answer certainly is. Thanks for the link

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`var` is a static class variable of `someClass`.

When you reach out to get `x.var`, `y.var` or `some_other_instance.var`, you are accessing the same variable, not an instance derived one (as long as you didn't specifically assigned it to the instance as a property).

Comment: So then when I use x.var = 2 I basically create a new variable in x that shadows the variable in someClass in this instance?

Comment: @pindakaas Bingo!