# How to initialize a variable inside a class from another file in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, oop, variables

I am working in a personal project in Python, and I faced a problem that includes three of the files in this project. Let's say the files are named `settings.py`, `functions.py` and `main.py`.

In `settings.py` I have a `class` named `settings`, and inside this `class` I have a **boolean variable** named `use_this_method` and its value is `False`.

I have imported this class in the `functions.py` file, and I'm trying to change and print the value of the variable `use_this_method` from `False` to `True`. It works, but after this I want to print its value in the same way in the `main.py` file, but it prints False instead of True.

`settings.py`

```
class settings:
    use_this_method = False
```

`functions.py`

```
from settings import settings
setting = settings()

def change_method():
    setting.use_this_method = True
    print(setting.use_this_method)
```

`main.py`

```
from functions import *
from settings import settings
setting = settings()

change_method()
print(setting.use_this_method)
```

In the output I am expecting:

```
True
True
```

but I get

```
True
False
```

Comment: You are changing the value on an instance, not the class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `setting` instance in your `functions.py` is separate from the one in your `main.py`. If you `print(id(setting))` in both modules you will see that.

You should use [class attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47070899/difference-between-instance-attributes-and-class-attributes) for your use case.Your `functions.py` then becomes:

```
from settings import settings

def change_method():
    settings.use_this_method = True
    print(setting.use_this_method)
```

and your `main.py`:

```
from functions import *
from settings import settings

change_method()
print(settings.use_this_method)
```

As a side note, it is a good idea to stick to Python naming conventions detailed in [PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) if you have just started learning Python.