# Classes and Python

Tags: python

I have a problem about Classes and I can explain it with Python codes. Code:

```
class Game:
    variable = 0
    def function(self):
        print("This is a message inside the class.")

a = Game()
a.variable += 1

a = Game()
a.variable += 1
print(a.variable)
```

I want to get result 2 when I am using it with classes. Let me explain why I want it. Because I am using socket and for every user in "Game" class online variable's value increasing 1. For every user It's creating new instance for Game class (in function connection_made). Because of creation of instance value is 1.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: Difference between class and instance attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/207000/python-difference-between-class-and-instance-attributes)

Comment: The `a` is being overwriten when you call `a = Game()` the second time.

Comment: either instantiate `a` once, or make `variable` static

Comment: You are loading the class into `a` when you have the second line of `a = Game()` thus erasing the first call to set variable to +=1.

Comment: @OmarEinea My first instinct was to say `variable` *is* ”static”, but of course only `Game.variable` not the `variable` attribute on the instances that gets created by `+=`. :-)

Comment: I also recommend reading this: [blog.lerner.co.il/python-attributes](http://blog.lerner.co.il/python-attributes/)

Comment: You may want to use `Game.variable` instead of `a.variable` ?

Answer (score 1):

If I understund it correctly, you want to count the instances of the class Game. Something like this will do the job:

```
class Game:
    _count = 0  # class attribute

    def __init__(self):
        Game._count += 1
        self.variable = Game._count  # instance attribute

    # rest of the code...

a = Game()
b = Game()
print(a.variable)  # 1
print(b.variable)  # 2
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, to explain it easier, you have to know that doing `a.variable += 1` is the same that doing `a.variable = a.variable + 1`.

Now, that being said, here is "the problem".
The thing here, is that when you access `a.variable`, the interpreter doesn't find the attribute in the instance, so it look that attribute on the class. When it find it, it will return that value. So, `a.variable = a.variable + 1` becomes `a.variable = 0 + 1`. Now, the interpreter will go to the instance, and look for the attribute `variable`. It doesn't find it, so it create it and set it as one.
But what? Then you never changed the attribute `variable` from the class `Game`? The answer is no. To check this, try this code.

```
class Game:
    variable = 0
    def function(self):
        print("This is a message inside the class.")

a = Game()
print('Instance attributes before set:', a.__dict__)
print('Class attributes before set', Game.__dict__)
a.variable += 1
print('Instance attributes before set:', a.__dict__)
print('Class attributes after set:', Game.__dict__)
```

As you can see, you never changed the class atribute. If you want to change the class attribute, you have to do

```
Game.variable += 1
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

`a.variable += 1` is short for `a.variable = a.variable + 1`.  What happens here is that `a.variable` on the right hand side of the assignment refers to `Game.variable` and has the value 0 and then a *new instance* attribute `variable` is created on `a` with the value 0+1=1.  `Game.variable` is never changed, i.e. assigned a new value.

If you want to increase `Game.variable` you actually have to assign the incremented value to the class `Game`, not instances.

Having said that: You don't really want to have global counters of things on classes. This is not flexible and it is error prone.  Have a container with user objects somewhere to keep track of the users and query that container for its length if you need to know the number of users.