# Python Classes properties and namespaces

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, scope

I have a few questions regarding programming terminologies.

1)I have the following code:

```
class Dog(object):
        population = 0               ## class variable--for every instance of Dog, population will be increase by 1            
        def __init__(self, name):   
            self.name = name        
            self.num_legs = 4
            Dog.population += 1     ## <== add 1 to Dog population
        def get_num_legs(self):     
            return self.num_legs

dog1 = Dog('dog1')  
dog2 = Dog('dog2')

print(Dog.population)
print(dog1.population)


## What happened?##  
dog1.num_legs = 2  #changes the instance property of dog1
print("Dog1 has {} legs".format(dog1.get_num_legs()))
print("Dog2 has {} legs".format(dog2.get_num_legs()))
Dog.num_legs = 10  #changes the class variable of Dog Class
dog1 = Dog('dog1')  ## An instance of class dog

dog2 = Dog('dog1')

print("Dog1 has {} legs".format(dog1.get_num_legs()))
print("Dog2 has {} legs".format(dog2.get_num_legs()))
```

The output to this code is 2,4,4,4, and I would think that the reason why the class variable `num_legs` will not ever be shown to be `10` when we do `print(instance.num_legs)` is we always check whether the instance has a property of `num_legs` before we try to read from the class variable(In this case there will always be that property).

> However, this is just my laymen interpretation and I'm trying to find out what's the explanation with programming terminologies. Is it something similar to the namespaces and scopes in nested functions?

Comment: Please don't ask two different questions in the same question. Ask about class/instance attributes *or* nested functions, but not both.

Comment: @Aran-Fey I'm actually trying to figure out whether class and instances attributes can be thought of as a model similar to the scoping idea in nested functions, but either way I'm not sure of both. Is that legal?

Comment: A picture is worth a thousand words: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34126204/476