# Problem with accessing dictionaries in multiple objects in Python

Tags: python, class, dictionary

I am a Python noobie, and I'm experiencing some problems with grasping how does the dictionary work in Python.

I created a class:

```
class Test:
    dictionary = dict()

    def __init__(self, id):
        self.id = id

    def add(self, key, val):
        self.dictionary[key] = val

    def print(self):
        print("id: " + str(self.id))
        print(self.dictionary.items())
```

I am executing this code:

```
list = [Test(0), Test(1)]
list[0].add(0, 0)
list[1].add(1, 1)

for t in list:
    t.print()
```

The desired effect of this code is to get:

```
id: 0
dict_items([(0, 0)])
id: 1
dict_items([(1, 1)])
```

But instead I get:

```
id: 0
dict_items([(0, 0), (1, 1)])
id: 1
dict_items([(0, 0), (1, 1)])
```

Why does this happen? And what should I do to get the desired effect? It seems that the dictionary shares the same memory despite it belonging to two different instances of the same class.

Comment: Because, a class attribute is shared by all instances, whereas, instance attribute is specific to that instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because `dictionary` is a class attribute. Make it an instance attribute.

Take a look at [What is the difference between class and instance attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/207000/what-is-the-difference-between-class-and-instance-attributes).

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self, id):
        self.id = id
        self.dictionary = dict()
```

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring a dictionary as attribute of the `class`, but you want it as attribute of the `instances`:

```
class Test:

    def __init__(self, id):
        self.id = id
        self.dictionary = {}
...
```