# How do I add these two variables and output correctly?

Tags: python-3.x

I am relatively new to python and am working on a text based rpg game written in python to improve at it. While trying to set my player's attack damage equal to its strength + weaponattack, I keep running into a problem. The two variables don't add.

```
class player:

    strength = 10
    weaponattack=0
    attack = strength + weaponattack

#other code outside of class

    player.weaponattack = 10
    print(player.attack)
```

I expect print(player.attack) to output 20, yet it outputs 10. Could someone please tell me how to fix this?

Comment: Those variables are set upon creating an instance of the class, editing one won't change another.. If you want that effect you could create a function of the class to update ```attack```, and call each time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several problems here, the main one is that you are using class attributes instead of instance attributes (for more info see [What is the difference between class and instance attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/207000/what-is-the-difference-between-class-and-instance-attributes)).

Second, `attack = strength + weaponattack` is evaluated only at definition time. The fact that you later modify `weaponattack` does not force `attack` to be re-evaluated (and re-calculated).

A good solution will be to use a property:

```
class Player:
    def __init__(self):
        self.strength = 10
        self.weaponattack = 0

    @property
    def attack(self):
        return self.strength + self.weaponattack

player = Player()

print(player.attack)
player.weaponattack = 10
print(player.attack)
```

Outputs

```
10
20
```

Comment: What's weird though is when I do print(player.weaponattack) outside of the class it would still give me the correct output(10).