# How to change an object atribute through a function in python

Tags: python, function, class, variables, attributes

I have a class, and I created two instances of it ,object1 and object2, I addend an attribute to each called "number", I want to be able to choose to which class I apply a function that I have created to change the "number"attribute, I managed to create the function but when i execute it only does it at a local level in the function, it does not return the result to the original object1.number instance, I assumne the problem is in how I positioned my variables.

So i want my global object1.number attribute to be changed inside the number_changer function and then be able to see that change outside the function.

I have used the print function along the code to follow the process, and it seems to do well, just its unable to change the global attribute

```
class ClassA():    
    pass


object1 = ClassA()    
object1.number = "0"    
object2 = ClassA()    
object2.number = "1"    


current_object = "object1"    
x = input("new number ")    

print(object1.number)    


def number_changer(object_name,new_number):    
    variable = object_name + ".number"    
    global object1    

    ref_obj_list = ["object1.number", "object2.number"]    
    real_obj_list = [object1.number, object2.number]    
    count = -1    
    for item in ref_obj_list:    
        count += 1    
        if variable == item:    
            real_obj_list[count]  = new_number    
            d = real_obj_list[count]    

            return d    




print(number_changer(current_object,x))    

print(object1.number)
```

when I put the number "5" in the input the result is this

```
0    
5    
0
```

the object1.number attribute does not change or at least not in a global level

Comment: I'm calling "x/y problem" on this question.  What problem are you trying to solve with this indirect code?  You manipulate object attributes outside the class.  You go out of your way to hard-code an indirect relationship between each object and the name of the variable.  You hand-code your own indexing loop.  You can bypass virtually all of this with `object1.number = input("new number ")`.

Comment: @PatrickArtner I want to change the number attribute of my objects, but I will not always know which object I will change the attribute, the purpose of the function is to detect the object an then change it.

Comment: @Prune I cant do that , because I will not always know the object to be changed, the variable "current_object" will also be an input, that kinda of be generated randomly, thats what the function does, find the object to change the attribute.

Comment: ... You are only replacing the value inside your local list inside your function with a string - nothing modifies the original ClassA() instances numbers ...

Comment: I'm still confused as to the interface design -- you're requiring that the user know all of your internal variable names, a clear violation of interface practices.  What problem are you solving with this?

Comment: See the addendum to my answer regarding attributes. You are probably looking for a dictionary to choose your instances by user input. The design is flawed though - why should your users know some kind of internal name for your instances ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of your code is superflous. If you pass an object to a function and access a non-existing attribute you get an error. If you set an attribute it will create it if not existing or change it if already existing:

```
class A:
    pass 


a1 = A()
a2 = A()

def changer(o,newtext):
    try:
        o.text = o.text + newtext
    except AttributeError:            # happens if the attribute does not exist
        print(".text does not exist")

a1.text = "whatever"
a2.text = "never"

print(a1.text, a2.text)  # prints whats being set
changer(a1,"changed")    # changes a1.text
print(a1.text, a2.text)  # prints changed text

changer(A(),"hallo")  # prints the caught/handled exception - A() has no .text
```

Output:

```
whatever never
whateverchanged never
.text does not exist
```

The "normal" way to do this would be to simpy add `text` to the class:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.text = None
```

that way it exists all the time and is unique to each instance.

See [What is the difference between class and instance attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/207000/what-is-the-difference-between-class-and-instance-attributes) for explanation of instance and (shared) class attributes

---

To select an object by user input, use a dictionary:

```
myAs = {"A1":a1, "A2":a2}   # a1,a2 from above

print(a1.text, a2.text)    
whichOne = input("Which element to change? " +  repr(list(myAs.keys())))
if whichOne in myAs:
    changer( myAs[whichOne],"YeHaa")
    print(a1.text, a2.text)
```

Output:

```
whateverchanged never
Which element to change? ['A1', 'A2'] A2
whateverchanged neverYeHaa
```

Comment: Thanks your code helped me a lot, Im just learning so I really dont uderstand the whole picture. These user inputs i want it to be deliver to the program later, like from an API, Im unsure on how that works.

Comment: Here is the code I wanted it, as you said is some kind of dictionary , so i dont know the object to change, My final code is at the end

Answer (score 2):

In Python, objects are passed by reference, so if you change any attribute of that object inside a function/method, it will be changed no matter if you use `global` or not.

The problem I am seeing in your logic is that you are never changing the value of the attribute, you should do something as:

```
object1.number = 123 # this is going to change that attribute no matter if you use the global keyword
```

Answer (score 0):

In your function, by using this line:

```
real_obj_list[count]  = new_number
```

you are not changing the actual object's value, you are just changing the value in the `real_obj_list` array.

I don't see what's wrong with using a simple assignment:

```
object1.number = 1
```

(which is nowhere to be seen in your function, hence the value is not updating).

But if you want a function for it, @PatrickArtner's answer pretty much sums it up.

Answer (score 0):

If I change the value of current_object it will change the attribute as desired, want I wanted was to be able to choose in which object I will apply the attribute changer, that was why I could not use the direct way, thanks a lot.

```
current_object = "a"    
def matcher(object):    
    ref_list = ["a","b","c"]    
    real_list = [a,b,c]    
   count = -1    
    for item in ref_list:    
        count += 1    
        if item == object:    
            d = real_list[count]    
            return d    


class A():    
    pass    

a = A()    
b = A()    
c = A()    

var = matcher(current_object)    

def changer(o,newtext):    
    o.text =  newtext    

a.text = "bye"    
b.text = "hello"    
c.text = "Dunno"    

print(a.text)    
print(b.text)    
print(c.text)    

changer(var,"works")    

print(a.text)    
print(b.text)    
print(c.text)
```