# How to fix a "NameError: name 'color' is not defined"?

Tags: python, python-3.x

here is my code :

```
size = (1280, 850)
Win = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
class Particle:
    color = (255, 255, 0)
    ID = 0

    def __init__(self, rect):
        Particle.ID += 1
        self.color = (color)
        self.ID = Particle.ID
        self.rect = rect

    def move(self, x, y):
        self.rect.move(x, y)

    def draw(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(Win, self.color, self.rect)

    def collide(self, rect1):
        return self.rect.colliderect(rect1)
```

When I run my project, I have : "self.color = (color)
NameError: name 'color' is not defined" but color is defined...It is at the beginning of my class "Particle"...

Thank you to help me !

Comment: `color` -> `self.__class__.color` to access the class variable. It is not a good idea to name an instance variable like a class variable - this easiliy leads to errors.

Comment: What are you trying to do? You have the color as a class variable, and then you are trying to assign an instance variable with the same name?

Comment: Or just `self.color`

Comment: Your problem is that there is no symbol named `color` in your `__init__` function, but I have the feeling you try to achieve something else there.

Comment: You don't have variable 'color' in your __init__, so it's senseless to assign class variable to instance variable - it will have it by default. But you can do something like
    MyParticle = Particle(some_rect)

Comment: The `color` class attribute will be accessible for all its instances, no need to define it in the `__init__` method. If you want to create another variable based on `color`, please rename it. It you want to get the `rect` color, you can write `self.color = rect.color`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between class and instance attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/207000/what-is-the-difference-between-class-and-instance-attributes)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fact you defined `color` in the class's namespace (making it a class attribute) doesn't make it available in methods bodies. Names in a method (actually a function) body are resolved at function execution time, not at function definition time, and at this point the `color` varibale defined in the class body has already be turned into a class attributes - they are not part of the function's non-local namespace.

Now the "proper" solution depends on what you want to achieve.

If all of your particle instance should share the same "color" value, just keep the class attribute and remove the instance one in your initializer - class attributes can be accessed directly from the instances, so `self.color` will automagically resolve to `type(self).color`. Note that this won't prevent you to assign per-instance color values - the class attribute is only accessed thru the instance if the instance has no attribute by that name, so setting `your_particle.color = something_else` (or `self.color = ...` - just the same) later in your code will still create an instance attribute and shadow the class-level one - but this is usually considered bad practice as it doesn't make the intent clear.

If you want per-instance colors, the best solution is to get rid of the class level attribute and only set the color in the initializer ie

```
class Particle:

    # better to make this an implementation attribute
    _ID = 0

    @classmethod
    def _next_id(cls):
        cls._ID += 1
        return cls._ID

    def __init__(self, rect):
        self.ID = self._next_id()
        self.color = (255, 0, 0)
```

or (if you want to be able to specify the color at instantiation time):

```
    def __init__(self, rect, color=(255, 0, 0)):
        self.ID = self._next_id()
        self.color = color
```

Answer (score 1):

Technically spoken: You dont need the instance attributes, `color` and `ID` are already available:

```
class Particle:
    color = (255, 255, 0)
    ID = 0

    def __init__(self, rect):
        Particle.ID += 1
        self.rect = rect

        print(self.ID)
        print(self.color)

p = Particle(None)
```

Output:

```
1
(255, 255, 0)
```

**Note**: In case you really need `color` and `ID` as **instance variables**, use a another name:

```
class Particle:
    color = (255, 255, 0)
    ID = 0
    def __init__(self, rect):
        Particle.ID += 1
        self.rect = rect
        self.pcolor = self.color
        self.pID = self.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the line `self.color = (color)` in order to make your code working.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/25376377)

Comment: @SimasJoneliunas This *is* an answer. See B--rian's edit.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have variable `color` in your `__init__()`, so it's senseless to assign class variable to instance variable - it will have it by default. But you can do something like

```
MyParticle = Particle(some_rect)
MyParticle.color = (255, 0, 255)
```

Comment: I did this : 

`class Particle:
    color = (255, 255, 0)
    def __init__(self, rect):
        self.color = self.color`

Answer (score 0):

A couple comments. Since you define color as a class variable, you probably don't want to reassign it as an instance variable. Just use it directly with `Particle.color` (see `draw` below). If you want to keep track of IDs you can just use `id(object)`. You can use your existing strategy for `ID` as a count though.

```
class Particle:
    color = (255, 255, 0)

    def __init__(self, rect):
        self.rect = rect

    def move(self, x, y):
        self.rect.move(x, y)

    def draw(self):
        print(Particle.color, self.rect) # pygame.draw.rect

p = Particle("Rectangle dimensions")                                   
id(p)                                                                  
> 4559902608

p2 = Particle("Rectangle dimensions")
id(p2)
> 4559964496
```

Answer (score -4):

I cannot comment yet.

Try this:

```
self.color = (color) -> self.color = color
```

Edit:
Let me correct, I do not have the full context of your implementation of the class. You have to initialize the class as an object because the funciton draw cals the color in the self container. Hence you have to create the object, then call the draw function from the object. Thus Particle.draw() will not work because the classes initializer is not called.

Thus:

```
particle = Particle()
particle.draw()
```

Comment: You should still be able to try it out in an online editor like ideone or repl.it.

Comment: Let me correct, I do not have the full context of your implementation of the class. You have to initialize the class as an object because the funciton draw cals the color in the self container. Hence you have to create the object, then call the draw function from the object. Thus Particle.draw() will not work because the classes initializer is not called.

Comment: If you cannot comment yet, it's better to invest 15 minutes to get the minimum rep required, rather than to post a non-answer. Also, we're not going to "bare" with you. :laugh: