# Error is thrown while practicing Inheritance in Python 3

Tags: python, inheritance, parent-child

WHen I execute, it throws the error:

```
 ....
  ......
    class Dog(Pet):
  File "D:\untitled2\Pet.py", line 13, in Dog
    Dog.numberoflegs = 4
NameError: name 'Dog' is not defined
Fish.numberoflegs = 0
NameError: name 'Fish' is not defined
```

please help

```
class Pet:
    numberoflegs = 0
    def sleep(self,name):
        print("the {} sleeps".format(name))
    def countlegs(self):
        print("I have {} legs".format(self.numberoflegs))


#type = input("enter pet type")
#dog.sleep(type)

class Dog(Pet):
    Dog.numberoflegs = 4
    def bark(self):
        print ("the dog sounds woof")

class Fish(Pet):
    Fish.numberoflegs = 0


kuta = Dog()
kuta.countlegs()
kuta.bark()
machi = Fish()
machi.countlegs()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Class attributes are simply added to the class - not prefixed by the class name:

```
class Dog(Pet):
    numberoflegs = 4
    # etc

class Fish(Pet):
    numberoflegs = 0
```

You can change it using `Dog.numberoflegs = 3` (if you have 3-legged dogs by default).

Classattributes are shared between all instances.

See

- [What is the difference between class and instance attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/207000/what-is-the-difference-between-class-and-instance-attributes)
- https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/ for some styling tips - your naming convention differ quite a bit from whats suggested

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time for such a detailed explanation! :) I just started to learn web application development using python 3.7. could you recommend some better tutorial as the one I am currently following, has such issues as you noticed.

Comment: I just tried to run my above code using separate files for each animal, inheriting the animal super class within the same project directory. now it doesn't throw any exception. But no output is shown what I was expecting by running the mian.py containing `kuta = Dog()
kuta.countlegs()
kuta.bark()
machi = Fish()
machi.countlegs()`

Comment: @kederr The -1 answer has the internal link for the +130 / +145 rated duplicate in it. But youre ofcourse correct - change the link to be direct instead of indirect

Answer (score 0):

you can define your class `Dog` in this way:

```
class Dog(Pet):
    numberoflegs = 4
    def bark(self):
        print ("the dog sounds woof")
```

your class attribute `numberoflegs` do not need `Dog.`

you are getting the error because you are trying to use the class at "creation" time, before to even have the `Dog` class

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
class Dog(Pet):
    Dog.numberoflegs = 4
```

to:

```
class Dog(Pet):
    numberoflegs = 4
```

It already has the scope of the class, and you can't refer to the class by name yet since it's still being defined.