# Python : How is sub class variable accessible by superclass functions when called by an object of sub-class

Tags: python, inheritance, parent-child, subclass, superclass

```
initialTreeCom=['ADD_CHILD None King_Shan Male','ADD_CHILD None Queen_Anga Female',
                 'AM King_Shan Queen_Anga','ADD_CHILD Queen_Anga Chit Male']

famTree=familyTree.FamiltyTree(initialTreeCom)
result=famTree.excommand('GET_RELATIONSHIP Chit Father')
print(result)
```

Q1. when i create an object of class `FamilyTree` which inherits from class `Relationships` . how is a function called `excommand` of class `FamilyTree` able to call a function of parent class as

```
getattr(self, argument[2].replace('-','_'))(argument[1])
```

but throws an error when i get the function reference by gettr function by using `super` (since i want to access function of parent class) instead of `self`?

Q2. How is the called function `Father` of super class `Relationships` able to access variable `familyMembers` of subclass `FamilyTree` using `self.familyMembers` ?

```
    class Person():
            def __init__(self,mother,name,gender):
                self.name=name
            self.gender=gender
            self.mother=mother
            self.marriedTo=None

        def add_partner(self,marriedTo):
            """
            Assigns passed marriedTo value to marriedTo attribute to calling objects
            """
            if marriedTo != self.marriedTo:
                self.marriedTo=marriedTo

    class FamiltyTree(Relationships):
        familyMembers=OrderedDict()
        def __init__(self,initialTree):        
            for i,line in enumerate(initialTree):
                # print('executing command',i,' : ',line)
                self.excommand(line)

        def excommand(self,command):
            """
            Executes the passed command
            Commands : ADD_CHILD, GET_RELATIONSHIP
            """
            argument=command.split()
            if argument[0]=='ADD_CHILD':
                # print('adding child')
                p=Person(argument[1], argument[2], argument[3])
                return self.add_Person(p)
            if argument[0]=='AM':
                # print('adding married to')
                return self.add_MarriedTo(argument[1], argument[2])
            if argument[0]=='GET_RELATIONSHIP':
                if argument[1] not in self.familyMembers:
                    return 'PERSON_NOT_FOUND'
                # print('getting relationship',argument[2], 'for : ',argument[1])
                **res= getattr(self,argument[2].replace('-','_'))(argument[1])**
                if res:
                    return ' '.join(res)
                return None

        def add_Person(self,person):
            """
            Adds passed Person to Family members, of calling object of FamiltyTree
            """
            if person.mother!='None' and  person.mother not in self.familyMembers:
                return 'PERSON_NOT_FOUND'
            if isinstance(person,Person) and person.name not in self.familyMembers and (person.mother=='None' or self.familyMembers[person.mother].gender=='Female'):
                self.familyMembers[person.name]=person
                return 'CHILD_ADDITION_SUCCEEDED'
            else:
                return 'CHILD_ADDITION_FAILED'

        def add_MarriedTo(self,person1,person2):
            """
            sets marriedTo Relationship among both passed person objects to each other.
            """
            if person1 in self.familyMembers and person2 in self.familyMembers:
                for key , value in self.familyMembers.items():
                    if key==person1:
                        value.add_partner(person2)
                    if key==person2:
                        value.add_partner(person1)
                return True
            else:
                return False

    class Relationships():

        def Father(self,name):
            """
            Finds Father of passed person name
            """
            if name in self.familyMembers:
                for key , value in self.familyMembers.items():
                    if self.familyMembers[self.familyMembers[name].mother].marriedTo==key:
                        return key
            return None
```

Answer (score -1):

A1. `getattr()` is searching for a member whose name corresponds to the string you pass it.  In your case, the name is `Father`.  This is a convenient way of mapping strings the user inputs (`argument[2]` in your case) so that you can see if an implementation of that relationship exists in the `Relationships` class.

This is clever.  Now you can just add implementations for other relationships to the Relationship class without having to modify the implementation of `GET_RELATIONSHIP`.

Alternatively, you could have implemented `Father` as:

```py
if argument[2] == 'Father':
   res = self.Father(argument[1])
```

But then you'd have do that for every type of relationship you want to implement (eg, `Brother`, `Cousin`).

This `Relationships` class makes it easy for you to just implement individual relationships by walking the family tree.  The `Father()` implementation is a good example of how to do that.

A2. Because when Python encounters `self.x`, it first searches the current class for a data attribute `x`, and if it finds none, it then proceeds to search for a class attribute `x`, and uses that for subsequent operations on `self.x`.  In your case, `familyMembers` is class attribute, and it happens to be located in the superclass `Relationships`.  `super` only looks at data members.

There is an excellent discussion of class and instance attributes [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/207000/what-is-the-difference-between-class-and-instance-attributes)

Comment: yes i added getattr() for the same reason . my question is why am i able to access a function of parent class using 'self' , whereas my first instinct was to use 'super' , but to my surprise it threw error.

in Q2 i am basically confused as to how the superclass functions are able to access a child class's class member using 'self' .