# Clear directories after unit testing in Python using tearDownClass

Tags: python, unit-testing, oop

I wonder how we can clear the directories after unit test in Python. I need to do it inside the classmethod `tearDownClass` instead of `tearDown` because I only want to clear this up once all the tests are done, not after every single test. The reason of this is that the created files and directories will be used in the next tests. But, at the same time, I also want to pass the directory path to `setUp` because I need that to instantiate my object. For example:

```
import unittest
import os
import pandas as pd


class Class1():
    def __init__(self,in_dir,out_dir):
        self.in_dir = in_dir
        self.out_dir = out_dir
        self.excel_path = os.path.join(self.out_dir,'Excels')

    def create_dir(self):
        os.makedirs(self.excel_path)
        text = {'text':['ABC']}
        df = pd.DataFrame(text)
        df.to_csv(os.path.join(self.excel_path,'test1.csv'))

    def use_csv(self):
        for root,dirs,files in os.walk(self.excel_path):
            df = pd.DataFrame()
            for file in files:
                df_append = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(root,file))
                df = df.append(df_append)
        return df


class TestA(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.in_dir = './in_dir'
        self.out_dir = './out_dir'
        self.C = Class1(self.in_dir, self.out_dir)

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        #how to call out_dir in this classmethod?
        if not os.path.exists(cls.out_dir):
            os.makedirs(cls.out_dir)

    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):
        #how to call out_dir in this classmethod?
        shutil.rmtree(cls.out_dir)


    def test_1(self):
        self.C.create_dir()
        self.assertEqual(len(os.listdir(self.C.excel_path)),1)

    def test_2(self):
        self.assertIsInstance(self.C.use_csv(),pd.DataFrame)
```

If I clear up the directories using `tearDown` I will remove the generated `test1.csv` after testing `test_1`, hence, I'm thinking to use `tearDownClass` instead.

Thanks!

Comment: Just have `in_dir` and `out_dir` be declared at the class scope, or declare them inside `setUpClass` and assign like `cls.in_dir = './in_dir'`.  That said, you may wish to consult the [`tempfile.TemporaryDirectory`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.TemporaryDirectory) helper class to better manage this for you.

Comment: If I declare it inside ```setUpClass```, how can I pass it to ```setUp```? Since I need to pass it as argument to instantiation of ```self.C```. Thanks!

Comment: Attributes assigned to the `cls` will be accessible from the instance itself via `self`.

Comment: so I declare ```cls.in_dir = './in_dir'``` inside ```setUpClass(cls)```. Then how do I call it inside ```setUp```? ```cls.in_dir``` or ```self.in_dir``` or how? Thanks a lot

Comment: `self.in_dir`, as the name `cls` is not a name available in the methods you have defined. As I said before, class attributes of any given name are accessible as instance attributes under the same name.  Please review [the difference between class and instance attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/207000/what-is-the-difference-between-class-and-instance-attributes), the flowchart in one of the replies describe how Python returns the values assigned when accessing e.g. `self.in_dir`.

Comment: Ah I see! It works! Thanks a lot @metatoaster