# Why does this list within a class not update properly?

Tags: python

So I have the following code:

```
class Table:
    children = [False, False]

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.children)


classroom = [Table(), Table(), Table(), Table()]


def update():
    classroom[1].children[0] = True
    print(classroom)


update()
```

Which is supposed to edit the second element within the list "classroom" and print out:

`[[False, False], [True, False], [False, False], [False, False]]`

But somehow updating the list on line 12 updates every instance of the class, giving me this:

`[[True, False], [True, False], [True, False], [True, False]]`

I've tried using the global keyword within the function but it seems to have no affect, am I missing something?

Comment: `children` is a class variable, meaning its shared between all instances of `Table`. You need to make it an instance variable if you want them to have different values.

Comment: Also check https://stackoverflow.com/q/207000/4046632

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`children` is a class variable, associated with the class rather than the instance. When you change it on one occasion, it gets updated in every existing instance of that class - the four instances of `Table` in your case.

To achieve the desired behavior you need to make `children` an instance variable. One common way to do it is to introduce an `__init__` method that is called when you create an instance,

```
class Table:

    def __init__(self):
        self.children = [False, False]

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.children)
```

Now every instance of `Table`, when created, calls its own `__init__` and makes its own `children` list. Later, when you update the second `Table` the changes are correctly reflected only in that one case.

Comment: Gladly! Consider doing some more reading on class structure in Python, there are a few good things that are very helpful.