# Python OOP and lists

Tags: python, class-variables

I'm new to Python and it's OOP stuff and can't get it to work. Here's my code:

```
class Tree:

    root = None;
    data = [];

    def __init__(self, equation):
        self.root = equation;

    def appendLeft(self, data):
        self.data.insert(0, data);

    def appendRight(self, data):
        self.data.append(data);

    def calculateLeft(self):
        result = [];
        for item in (self.getLeft()):
            if (type(item) == type(self)):
                data = item.calculateLeft();
            else:
                data = item;
            result.append(item);
        return result;

    def getLeft(self):
        return self.data;

    def getRight(self):
        data = self.data;
        data.reverse();
        return data;

tree2 = Tree("*");
tree2.appendRight(44);
tree2.appendLeft(20);

tree = Tree("+");
tree.appendRight(4);
tree.appendLeft(10);
tree.appendLeft(tree2);

print(tree.calculateLeft());
```

It looks like tree2 and tree are sharing list "data"?

At the moment I'd like it to output something like [[20,44], 10, 4], but when I

```
tree.appendLeft(tree2)
```

I get `RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded`, and when i even won't `appendLeft(tree2)` it outputs `[10, 20, 44, 4]` (!!!). What am I missing here? I'm using Portable Python 3.0.1.

Thank you

Comment: I was confused by the same behaviour, and asked [this question, "Why do attribute references act like this with Python inheritance"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/206734/why-do-attribute-references-act-like-this-with-python-inheritance), which might be of interest

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is that you've declared `data` as a class variable, so all instances of the class share the same list.  Instead, put `self.data = []` in your `__init__`.

Also, get rid of all those semicolons.  They are unnecessary and clutter up your code.

Comment: Thanks, did't expect, that declaring them as class variable would make them 'global'. Finally can finish my homework now :).

Comment: Writing semicolons at the end of the line is just habit form java and PHP, will remove them :)

Answer (score 4):

Move root and data into the definition of `__init__` . As it stands, you have them defined as class attributes. That makes them shared among all instances of the Tree class. When you instantiate two Trees (`tree` and `tree2`), they both share the same list accessed with `self.data`. To make each instance have its own instance attribute, you must move the declaration into the `__init__` function.

```
def __init__(self, equation):
    self.root = equation
    self.data = []
```

Also, use

```
        if isinstance(item,Tree):        # This is True if item is a subclass of Tree
```

instead of

```
        if (type(item) == type(self)):   # This is False if item is a subclass of Tree
```

and change

```
data = self.data
```

to

```
data = self.data[:]
```

in `getRight`. When you say `data = self.data` then the variable name `data` points at the very same list that `self.data` points at.
When you subsequently reverse `data`, you reverse `self.data` as well.
To reverse only `data`, you must copy the list. `self.data[:]` uses slicing notation to return a copy of the list. Note that the elements of `self.data` can be `Tree`s, and `self.data` and `self.data[:]` can contain identical elements. I don't think your code requires these elements to be copied, but you'll need to recursively copy `self.data` if that is the case.

```
def getRight(self):
    data = self.data[:]
    data.reverse()
    return data
```

Comment: Thank you for your note conserning copying lists. This was probably going to be my next problem.

Answer (score 3):

When you define attributes in the following way:

```
class Tree:
    root = None
    data = []
```

..that empty list object is created as Python defines the class, not when you create a new instance. It is a class attribute, not an instance attribute. Meaning, `Tree.root` is the same object in all instances:

```
class Tree:
    root = None
    data = []

t1 = Tree()
t2 = Tree()

print id(t1.data) == id(t2.data) # is True, they are the same object
```

To get the behaviour you expect, move the creation of the empty list to the `__init__` function, which is only called when you create a new instance, and only alters that instance (as it assigns to `self`):

```
class Tree:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = None
        self.data = []

t1 = Tree()
t2 = Tree()

print id(t1.data) == id(t2.data) # False, they are different objects
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206734/why-do-attribute-references-act-like-this-with-python-inheritance/206765#206765) explains why such behaviour can be useful