# python - list assignment inside function

Tags: python, class, variable-assignment

I am new to Python and I am trying to use a function to add elements to an object owned list.
Here is a simplified version of my code:

```
class TElement:
    vec = []

class GTop:

    ElList = []

    def AddElement(self, vect):
        NewEl = TElement() 
        for i in range(len(vect)): 
            NewEl.vec.append(vect[i])

        self.ElList.append(NewEl)


myvec1 = ["a",1,2,"b"]
myvec2 = ["a","c",2,"b"]

Mytop = GTop()

Mytop.AddElement(myvec1)

Mytop.AddElement(myvec2)
```

With the above code I get:

Mytop.ElList[0].vec = ['a', 1, 2, 'b']

Mytop.ElList[1].vec = ['a', 1, 2, 'b', 'a', 'c', 2, 'b']

While I wanted:

Mytop.ElList[0].vec = ['a', 1, 2, 'b']

Mytop.ElList[1].vec = ['a', 'c', 2, 'b']

For some reason, when I exit the AddElement function NewEl is not being deleted.
Could you clarify what I am doing wrong?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change `TElement` like this you should get the output you expected:

```
class TElement:
    def __init__(self):
        self.vec = []
```

As @delnan pointed out in a comment, read the other answer, it explains well.

[Why do attribute references act like this with Python inheritance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206734/why-do-attribute-references-act-like-this-with-python-inheritance)