# Python : Behavior of class and instance variables

Tags: python, instance-variables, class-variables

I have following two code samples

Example 1:

```
class MyClass(object):

    def __init__(self, key, value):
         self._dict = self._dict.update({key:value})

m = MyClass('ten',10)
print m._dict
```

Output:

```
AttributeError: 'MyClass' object has no attribute '_dict'
```

Example2:

```
class MyClass(object):
    _dict = {}
    def __init__(self, key, value):
        self._dict = self._dict.update({key:value})

m = MyClass('ten',10)
print m._dict
```

Output:
     `None`

I am quite surprised with above behavior

Why the example2 compiled successfully by just addition of _dict = {}
line, and line present at class scope.
also why `None` output?
I believed class scope variables has no relation with instance variable 
(special with `self`)

Any Explaination?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `None` output is because `dict.update` returns None. It modifies the dictionary itself, but does not return anything. So you probably wanted `self._dict.update({key:value})`. However, `self._dict` doesn't exist at initialization. So it would make more sense to do `self._dict = {key: value}`. If you're trying to modify the object's *internal* dictionary, then you should do `self.__dict__.update({key:value})`. However, this is bad practice. A better idea would be to write `setattr(self, key, value)`. The reason Example2 is working successfully is because if you try to do `getattr(instance, thing)` (which is what `instance.thing` does), and `thing` is not in `instance.__dict__`, then `instance.__class__.__dict__` will be checked instead.

Answer (score 2):

Your 'example 2' defines a single dictionary at the class level.  All instances of the class will share that same dictionary, at least unless you reassign _dict on the instance.

See this question for a detailed explanation:
[Why do attribute references act like this with Python inheritance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206734/why-do-attribute-references-act-like-this-with-python-inheritance)

As for why you're getting `None` - the `update` method changes its dict in place, and returns `None`.

Answer (score 1):

Because the `_dict` in Example 2 is a class variable so it's an attribute of `MyClass` where as the _dict in Example 1 is an instance variable so it's a instance attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Example 1: you are trying to update an object that is yet to be created. therefore error.

Example 2: When working in the inner scope of the function, if you modify the variable it makes changes to the previously defined _dict. But if you assign the value, it makes a new variable with the same name in the inner scope.

This will work.

```
class MyClass(object):
    _dict = {}
    def __init__(self, key, value):
        self._dict.update({key:value})
```

This will not.

```
class MyClass(object):
    _dict = {}
    def __init__(self, key, value):
        self._dict = self._dict.update({key:value})
```

because you are doing an assigning operation. It makes a new variable. So no changes are made to the _dict in the outer scope. Your _dict in the outer scope is still empty and returns None.

Answer (score 0):

`self._dict` does not yet exist, so the first version raises that exception.  The second one actually falls through looking `_dict` up on the instance and instead updates the class attribute, then assigns the class-level dictionary to the instance-scope `_dict` attribute.