# Why python use different scope mechanisms in function and class?

Tags: python, namespaces, scope

Some code and descriptions:

```
# name_space.py

class Class1(object):
    var1 = 11
    def f1(self):
        print Class1.var1  # this will OK
        print var1  # this will be an error

def func_1():
    var1 = 11

    def func_2():
        print var1  # here will be OK

    func_2()
```

So, as we can see:

1. Define a function in a class, the inner function doesn't have the ability to access the variables directly in the outer class. (We can still access the variables with the class name).
2. Define a function in a function, the inner function has the ability to access the variables directly in the outer function.

More codes:

```
# name_space2.py

class A(object):
    def f1(self):
        def f2():            
            print f1  # this will be an error
            print A.f1  # this will OK
        f2()
```

So, why python use different scope mechanisms in function and class?

Comment: Those are scopes, not namespaces.

Comment: you're code is strange, instead of `print Class1.var1  # this will OK` we'd rather see `print self.var1`. You're entirely new to python aren't you ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the *lifetime* and *visibility* of both is entirely different.

Class attributes are accessible by anything that can access the class. Class attributes also have to play with inheritance; what if I wrote code like this:

```
class Foo(object):
    def eggs(self):
        print eggs()

class Bar(Foo):
    def ham(self):
        print eggs()
```

By your logic, why should `eggs` be visible in `Foo.eggs` but not in `Bar.ham`?

Function locals are only accessible to the function and anything nested within the function. Call the function again and you get a *fresh* set of variables.

So when you create a class instance and call a method on that instance, the class attributes could have been changed by other code in the meantime. Function closures (locals accessed in a nested scope) cannot be changed from outside the function.

You cannot treat the two scopes as the same at all.

Comment: Great help, thanks very much! Learn a lot from "So when you create a class instance and call a method on that instance, the class attributes could have been changed by other code in the meantime."

Answer (score 1):

You are describing two mostly unrelated things, which happen to have similar indentation..

```
class Class1(object):
    var1 = 11
```

This is defining a new attribute on the `Class1`, you would access the `var1` attribute either via `Class1.var1`, or inside one of the class's methods like `self.var1`, e.g:

```
class Class1(object):
    var1 = 11
    def f1(self):
        print self.var1
```

It's maybe more commonly seen in things like this:

```
class Class1(object):
    def mygetter(self):
        return 42
    def mysetter(self, val):
        print "mysetter got value of", val
    myprop = property(mygetter, mysetter)
```

..which you would use like this:

```
c = Class1()
print c.myprop # 42
c.myprop = 100 # prints "mysetter got value of 100"
```

Or often used for defining static attributes on classes, like this:

```
class Class1(object):
    THING = 1
    ANOTHER = "blah"
    ...
```

Remember these are defined at *class definition time*, so the attributes are shared between all instances of the class (something [I found initially confusing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206734/why-do-attribute-references-act-like-this-with-python-inheritance))

The second thing you describe is lexical scoping, where variables are available in enclosed functions, often used like this:

```
def outer():
    myvar = 42
    def inner():
        print myvar * 2
    return inner
```

Comment: The real difference is namespace and scope. Thanks very much! Gain a lot from you codes. And a little sorry,  this site allows me to accept only one answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is no different mechanism.

`var1` is not available inside method `f1` because method's code is executed in the namespace where the method is called. `var1` on the other hand exists in the class namespace.