# Class Attributes/Variables in Python

Tags: python, class

Two examples;

```
class Foo1:
    something = 0
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.something = n
```

and

```
class Foo2:
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.something = n
```

Both classes seem to have the same behaviour:

```
x = Foo1(42)
y = Foo2(36)
print x.something
# will print 42
print y.something
# will print 36
```

But in the class `Foo1` is the variable `self.something` (in the constructor) actually the variable `something` as defined at the beginning of the class? What is the difference here? Which way is preferred to use?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python: Difference between class and instance attributes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/207000/python-difference-between-class-and-instance-attributes)

Comment: Also, check the answers at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2923579/python-class-attribute and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/68645/static-class-variables-in-python. Each instances of Foo1 can access (and share) `something` with `x.__class__.something`

Comment: Yet another: http://stackoverflow.com/q/206734/2319400

Comment: Thank you. Sorry if this is a duplicate. I was missing the right terminology to look for an answer correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is, in the first case, you can access the data attribute without using an object (or instance). In the second case, you can't. Please check the following code snippet :

```
>>> class Foo1:
...     something = 0
...     def __init__(self, n):
...         self.something = n
... 
>>> Foo1.something
0
>>> class Foo2:
...     def __init__(self, n):
...         self.something = n
... 
>>> Foo2.something
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: class Foo2 has no attribute 'something'
>>>
```

Hope I could clarify. For more, please read this : https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#class-and-instance-variables

Comment: Would this be pythons equivalent to static variables in C?

Comment: I don't think C static variable concept is required for Python.

Answer (score 2):

`something` is not the same as `self.something`. When you access `x.something` or `y.something`, you are accessing the version that is bound to that instance. The original `something` is local to that `type` rather than an object from that type:

```
>>> Foo1.something
0
>>> Foo1(42).something
42
```