# reference instance attribute in child class

Tags: python, class, parent-child

I am trying to call an instance variable from a "parent" class **(subclass)** to it's "child" class **(subsubclass)**

```
class mainclass():
    def __init__(self):
        self.mainclassvar1 = "mainclass"

class subclass(mainclass):
    def __init__(self):
        self.subclassvar1 = "subclass"

    def changeval(self):
        self.subclassvar1 = "subclassedited"

class subsubclass(subclass):
    def __init__(self):
        self.subsubclassvar1 =  subclass.subclassvar1 #<- naturally this fails


def handler():
    main=mainclass()
    sub = subclass()
    sub.changeval()
    subsub = subsubclass()
    print(subsub.subsubclassvar1)# <- how do I achieve this? I would expect "subclassedited" but it doesn't
if __name__ == "__main__":
    handler()
```

The above does not work obviously but I am trying to show what I am trying to achieve in my head.

if I change the class **subsubclass(subclass)** as follows it semi-works:

```
class subsubclass(subclass):
    def __init__(self):
        subclass.__init__(self)
        self.subsubclassvar1 =  self.subclassvar1
```

however the returned value is the original default value of **subclass** instead of the expected **subclassedited**.

I am not sure if I should even be trying to do this but I've got some code where the logic has now come to this point and I want to try see if I can get details from the middle class in to the final child class in their final modified states instead of the defaults and without refactoring a lot of code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do attribute references act like this with Python inheritance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206734/why-do-attribute-references-act-like-this-with-python-inheritance)

Comment: I'm not sure. Are you saying that I cannot do what I am trying to do and should rather set class variables in my middle class which I can call from the very last class?

Comment: Each `__init__` should be calling the parent's `__init__` method, which will automatically set the other attributes on `self`. There's really no need to set `subsubclassvar1` to the value of the "parent's" `subclassvar1` attribute, because `self` itself should have `subclassvar1` already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each `__init__` method should be invoking the parent's `__init__` method, so that the instance is properly initialized for all the classes in the hierarchy.

```
class mainclass:
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.mainclassvar1 = "mainclass"

class subclass(mainclass):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.subclassvar1 = "subclass"

    def changeval(self):
        self.subclassvar1 = "subclassedited"

class subsubclass(subclass):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        # Not sure why you would really need this, but...
        self.subsubclassvar1 =  self.subclassvar1
```

There's no reason, though that `subsub.subclassvar1` should be related to `sub.subclassvar1`, though. Calling `sub.changeval()` has nothing to do with `subsub`.

Comment: okay, this actually moves me closer to what I want. Thanks @chepner. 
But my middle class **subclass** has a bunch of logic in it that changes the original instance variables that are set at init.  

So when I use super and call the required variable from my 3rd class I only get the original variable before they were changed. Am I approaching this wrong?

Comment: @LlewellynCrossley you'll have to call the methods of your super class in your class if that change is to be seen.

Comment: @LlewellynCrossley The methods change the variables for a particular *instance*. You seem to be confusing inheritance and instantiation somewhat.

Comment: yep, I've confused inheritance and instantiation. What I'm trying to do should be reading the data from a particular instance instead of using inheritance to read those values. my bad.